# What's my name? Produce the name of the language indirectly

Tags: popularity-contest

Produce only the name of a programming language using only the facilities of the language itself. The name of the language can only be invoked indirectly, i.e., from non custom environment variables, built-in functions or methods or the interpreter/compiler of the language. Output should be the name of the language only.

One example would be:

```
$ awk --v | awk 'NR<2 { print $2}'  # GNU Awk 3.1.8
Awk
```

The answer I select will be the one with the most up votes. In case of a tie, the shortest golfed version (separate or the only given answer), will be the tie breaker.

Comment: so using Java reflection API is not OK?

Comment: I didn't think of that, but that's okay too.

Comment: @George: Huh? Is that now a code-golf? Why? It wasn't before ...

Comment: @Joey: No it wasn't before, but it seemed like a code golf question, so I edited it and someone approved the edit.

Comment: @Joey: Code Golf is the tie breaker. I didn't put that TAG on originally, but George suggested it and I agreed.

Comment: As of now, Anon. has 6 votes, but Eelvex, the one you picked, has 5.

Comment: @George Edison: Sorry, I took out the [code-golf] tag you added, as it's not a code golf question. (See the edit comment for rationale.)

Comment: `print(reverse("emaNegaugnaL"))` C, J, and other one'rs excluded :(

Comment: There's still no solution in Haskell...

Comment: @Joey: Remedied.

Comment: should'nt this be community wiki?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### BASH, <s>17</s> 7

```
bash -c 'echo $0'
```

or even

```
echo ${0#-}
```

if you already run bash :D

**update**: `"echo $0"` gets `$0` expanded first so `'echo $0'` is the correct answer.

Comment: It's only dash-prefixed if it's a login shell and it's not a login shell if it's the one that runs your program.

Comment: @JB: thanks for pointing that out. I was using `"`s where I should have `'`s

Comment: Looks like this is the winner. :)

Comment: echo ${SHELL:5}

Answer (score 31):

### Whitespace

```
|  	 	 			
	
    		 	   
	
    		 	  	
	
    			 	  
	
    		  	 	
	
    			  		
	
    			    
	
    		    	
	
    		   		
	
    		  	 	
	


|
```

Comment: Not a real language, whitespace.

Comment: @Alexandru: http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/

Comment: Argh. Sorry Anthony, SE doesn't let me upvote you now.

Comment: That's all right. I myself have recently learned about this language.

Comment: That has to be the most esoteric language of them all.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your program has two fatal errors: (1) Letting S,T,L denote Space,Tab,Linefeed repsectively, the first instruction is at present `SSTSTSTTTL`, but should be `SSSTSTSTTTL` (*3* S's on the left) -- the 3rd `S` is needed to indicate the positive sign of the binary number following it (i.e. the ascii code for 'W' = 85 = 1010111 in binary, coded as the `L`-terminated string `TSTSTTTL`), and so on for the other ascii codes. (2) The prog's final `TLLL` should be `TLSSLLL`, where the `TLSS` is needed to output the final character from the stack, and `LLL` marks the end-of-program.

Comment: I'm basing the preceding comment on the [Whitespace tutorial](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), and I'm using [this WS interpreter](http://yagni.com/whitespace/whitespace) in Ruby. Following is the 153-char revised version of Anthony's program (using the same previous S-T-L notation), which outputs the string "Whitespace" when executed with that interpreter: `SSSTSTSTTTLTLSSSSSTTSTSSSLTLSSSSSTTSTSSTLTLSSSSSTTTSTSSLTLSSSSSTTSSTSTLTLSSSSSTTTSSTTLTLSSSSSTTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSTLTLSSSSSTTSSSTTLTLSSSSSTTSSTSTLTLSSLLL`

Answer (score 26):

### C

```
#define d(x) x(#x[3])
void main(){d(putchar);}
```

Comment: `putchar((int)(putchar)+3);`

Comment: `putchar("putchar"[3]);` I must have been an idiot an year ago.

Comment: Use the main parameter. ```main(a){putchar(a+66);}```

Answer (score 23):

### J,4

```
u:74
```

Having a short language name does kind of help.

Comment: Can be even shorter : `u:74`

Answer (score 23):

## Python - <strike>23</strike> 22

```
print`credits`[97:103]
```

Comment: you should leave out the space after `print`

Comment: What does the **`** do? I've never seen that.

Comment: Backticks are a deprecated alias for repr(). Backticks are gone in Python 3.x.

Comment: @0xKir So? Use them in code golf 'till they're gone.

Answer (score 19):

## Python (win32) - abuse of the random module

I'm not sure whether this actually *works.* Depends on the implementation.

```
print ''.join([(random.seed(835)==None)and'']+[chr(random.randint(64,90)) for x in range(3)]+[(random.seed(53281)==None)and'']+[chr(random.randint(64,90)) for x in range(3)])
```

Comment: How did you find that? It also works for me in Python 2.6.6 on linux.

Comment: Good to hear! 

I wrote a small bruteforcing tool to determine how you need to seed the random module to get a certain sequence. With a three-character sequence, this doesn't take too long - this script joins together two three-letter sequences to get "PYTHON" :)

Comment: The rest is using list comprehensions and other dirty tricks to get it to fit it in one line. You can find the bruteforcing tool [here](http://pastie.org/2375182) :)

Comment: And it works on my Python 3.1.2 (adding parentheses after `print`, of course).

Comment: Almost there: `generateSentence(50613, 73)[66:]` gives `'PYTHOCN'`.

Answer (score 17):

### BrainFuck

Just for fun (I know this isn't related to the purpose of the task.), I wrote this code...

```
+++++[><-+-+-><><>++<><>+++++<>+<]>>>+
+>><<+<>+><<>+[><-<<+>>><>+<><>++<]>[-<<<
+>>>]+<<+<[><->>+>><>+<<><+<<]>->-><>->
+++++<<>+++++<<>------>><>+.<<[-<>+<>->
+<]>>+><+<>><+><+[<]>-<><>-><<>-<<>+>-.<
+<><>+<>+[><>-<>-><<>-<>><-<><>-><><-+<
++---]>[+>]<<+><+.>><-<<+++++[>+<><><-]
>
+++.>+<+<>+++<>+.+>
-.<><+<+><+><><++>
+++<>+<+>>+<><>+<
+.<><+[->>+>><<++
+<>><++-<<-+-<>+]+
>
>
---.<
---
---
---
<>>
<-.
---
>-<
```

And when I replaced `<`,`>`,`[`,`]`,`.` with space...

```
+++++   -+-+-     ++    +++++  +     +
+    +  +    +   -  +     +    ++    -   
+    +  +    -  +    +    +    - -   - 
+++++   +++++   ------    +    -  +  - 
+    +  +    +  +    -    -    -   + -  
+    +  +    -  -    -    -    -    -+ 
++---   +    +  +    -  +++++  +     - 

+++  + +  +++  + + 
-    + +  +    ++ 
+++  + +  +    + 
+    + -  +    ++
+    ++-  -+-  + +


---  
---
---
---

 - 
---
 -
```

Answer (score 13):

**Piet, 47x2 pixels**

Using 5x5 codels:  [image: Piet program to print "Piet"]

Answer (score 12):

### Python

```
import sys;print sys.copyright[24:30]
```

This also works for me (sys.executable is '/usr/bin/python')

```
import sys;print sys.executable[9:]
```

Comment: Here is what i get from these: `Active` and `25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe`, so... no good

Comment: `import sys;print sys.subversion[0][1:]` works though

Comment: that's cheating... But I can cheat better: `eval.__doc__[144:150]`

Answer (score 11):

### brainfuck 101

```
++++++++[->++++++++++++>+>>++>+++<<<<<]>[->+>+>+>+<<<<]>+>++.>++.<-.<.>>----.<<---.>>>---.<<++.>---.
```

could probably be golfed slightly further, but it's 6am and I should get some sleep...

Answer (score 11):

### **C**

In the spirit of Anon's answer in C (considering a C file always has the extension .c). I'd suggest :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){puts(__FILE__+sizeof(__FILE__)-2);}
```

Comment: Much shorter, 25 chars, single line, `main(){puts(__FILE__+2);}`, assuming filename is a single letter, eg. `a.c`

Answer (score 7):

### Java

```
public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "";
        s = s.getClass().getName();
        s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1, 4);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: anon: Just submit another answer. This isn't a golf, so no need to keep it short.

Answer (score 6):

### C

Built using DevStudio 2005

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
  int i,j,i2;
  for (i=j=0,i2=200;i2<=200;i2-=19,j==putchar(32|(i2<'Q'&&i2>'+'&&(j<20||i<12||i>28))*3)+8?j=0,i2+=i,i+=putchar('\n')-8:(i2+=j,j+=2));
}
```

Slightly shorter version (with compiler warnings)

```
int i,j,k;
for (i=j=k=0;k<=0;k-=19,j==putchar(32|(k<-119&&k>-157&&j<20|i<12|i>28)*3)+8?j=0,k+=i,i+=putchar('\n')-8:(k+=j,j+=2));
```

Comment: first one will produce warning about main not being of type `int` using gcc.

Comment: You are not allowed to use the letter 'c'.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby - 27

```
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION[0..3]
```

Update from Chris Jester-Young's comment:

### Ruby - 24

```
puts RUBY_COPYRIGHT[0,4]
```

Updated from Hauleth:

### Ruby - 15

```
p`ruby -v`[0,4]
```

Comment: 1. `RUBY_COPYRIGHT` is shorter than `RUBY_DESCRIPTION`. 2. `[0,4]` is shorter than `[0..3]`.

Comment: Even shorter ```ruby -v`[0,4]``

Answer (score 5):

### cat 3

Create a file with the following content (source code)

```
cat
```

And run it like (execute the file):

```
$ cat filename
```

Comment: Neither indirect nor a language?

Comment: Everything that takes a string input and produces a string output can be considered a programming language.

Comment: Cat isn't a real language, because it isn't Turing-complete.

Comment: @kinokijuf There are plenty of useful languages which are not Turing-complete.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8412741/20713 for a partial list.

Comment: @ephemient: Cat is not only not turing complete, it isn't a language at all. It has no syntax, no grammer, no keywords. I don't know where bitmask got his definition - I don't follow it.

Comment: @userunknown It's hard to imagine `cat` being a language, and besides this violates the spirit of the question (uses the language name directly).  My comment was to refute the idea that "Cat isn't a real language, because it isn't Turing-complete".  It isn't a language for other reasons, but Turing-completeness isn't a good deciding factor.

Comment: Well, `cat` of course has a syntax. It accepts any input. (It is a regular grammar btw)

Answer (score 5):

## Clojure - 16 chars

```
(subs(str =)0 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 47

```
data H=Haskell deriving Show
main=print Haskell
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

Not short, but very indirectly.

```
4.times{|x|print((82+11.24*x+8.231*Math.tan(111.2*x)).floor.chr)}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Ruby (17)

`p 1299022.to_s 36`

Outputs `"ruby"`

Answer (score 5):

## Bash/Brainfuck/C

```
//bin/bash -c 'echo ${0##*/}'
#define p putchar
#define exit main(){p(p+67);p(10);}
exit
//++++++++[->++++++++++++>+>>++>+++<<<<<]>[->+>+>+>+<<<<]
//>+>++.>++.<-.<.>>----.<<---.>>>---.<<++.>---.
```

Comment: Wow! A polyglot! Next step: add Whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

### Brainfuck

```
>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
-----------------.
++++++++.
+++++.
--------.
+++++++++++++++.
------------------.
++++++++.
```

Comment: Br**n ! (five more to go ...)

Comment: @belisarius: Hm?

Comment: Br**n you.

Comment: you can make smaller with [...]: ++++++++++[>++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++<<<<-]>++++++.>>++++.<---.++++++++.+++++.--------.>>++.*<<---.++++++++.

Comment: This looks like typical [Git](http://git-scm.com/) output.

Comment: JBernado: Suggest an edit, then.

Comment: do you really need the first >?

Comment: Maybe that was just to cater for my buggy interpreter. This solution is obsolete, anyway :)

Comment: even smaller `++++++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++<<-]>.>++.<-.>---------.+++++.<+++++.>+++++++.<---.>----------.`

Answer (score 4):

### Perl

```
$^X=~/([a-z]+)[^\/]+$/;print$1,$/
```

Comment: I get only `per` as output (missing the final l).

Comment: @BioGeek: Is your `Perl` binary called `per`?

Comment: I also get `per`.  (My `$^X` says `/usr/bin/perl`.  The `[^\/]+` swallows the `l`.)

Comment: fixed: `$^X=~/([^\/]+)$/;print$1`, run with `-l` command line switch

Answer (score 4):

### Scala — 42

```
print(((1,1).getClass+"").substring(6,11))
```

**Update — 39 chars**

```
print(('a.getClass+"").substring(6,11))
```

Comment: Nice! A variant, same size: print((""+'a.getClass).split("\\b")(3))

Comment: I prefer it capitalized, but of course, it isn't golf anymore. So, for the pleasure of making variants: print(classOf[App].toString.split("\\W").map(_.capitalize).apply(1))

Comment: Same trick in 23 chars: (""+Map).patch(5,"",99)

Comment: And 16: (""+Map).take(5)

Comment: Or 13: `""+Map take 5`

Comment: I've hardly ever used symbols in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

**C - 34**

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment to the previous C entry. Same idea as above, but the filename can be anything.c

```
main(){puts(index(__FILE__,0)-1);}
```

Comment: Gah, but now I can't name my files "&raquo;\0<3ASCII.c"

Answer (score 4):

### ><> (Fish) (11)

Even better:

```
'>'::o2-oo;
```

Answer (score 3):

### Visual Basic (version 6.0)

```
MsgBox Right(Error(458), 12)
```

### VBScript

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Raise 458
MsgBox Right(Err.Description, 8)
```

### Both VB6 and VBScript

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Raise 458
D = Err.Description
MsgBox Mid(D, InStr(2, D, "V"))
```

Comment: The VBScript one produces "Bscript." on my computer.

Comment: You're a bad man.

Answer (score 3):

### QBasic (37)

I am using version 1.1 of the QBasic interpreter.

```
FOR x=0TO 5:?CHR$(PEEK(2588+x));:NEXT
```

Answer (score 3):

**Lua 25 Chars**

```
print(arg[-1]:match"%w+")
```

Or, analogue to the J B's [J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/whats-my-name-produce-the-name-of-the-language-indirectly/1138#1138) 17 chars:

```
print"\76\117\97"
```

Comment: `_VERSION:sub(1,3)`

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (13)

```
"#{$0[0..9]}"
```

Comment: +1 Clever... very clever.  Of course, this doesn't work if you've renamed the interpreter, or if you're, say, running it from a different directory.

Comment: Ps. `"#{$0}"10<` is three chars shorter. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Racket (45)

```
racket -e "(display(substring(banner)10 17))"
```

Answer (score 3):

### D(52)

using the extension of the source file

```
import std.stdio;void main(){write(__FILE__[$-1]);}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 39

This makes use of the `FullForm` name of the Mathematica icon.

```
StringTake[ToString[FullForm[\[MathematicaIcon]]],{3,13}]
```

Comment: What's that weird character? If we don't know, we can't run that.

Comment: That character is #63319. In Mathematica it has goes by the name of `\[MathematicaIcon]`. `StringTake` returns the string, "Mathematica" taken from the name of the character.

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell

```
$ShellId -replace '.*\.'
```

Comment: Well, I was going to beat your length by 1 with `$ShellId[10..19]-join''`, but then I realized you could just make it up by losing whitespace. And then I also realized this is a [tag:code-challenge] and not [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

```
php -v|php -r'echo fread(STDIN,3);'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Assembler

Assembled using A86, generates a Windows .COM (tested on XP)

```
inc cx
push bx
push bx
inc bp
dec bp
inc dx
dec sp
inc bp
push dx
and al,72
mov ah,9
mov dx,si
inc sp
pop si
pop cx
int 21h
ret
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a »Windows .COM« :-)

Comment: Yes there is... ?

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy - 34

```
print "${''.metaClass.name}"[0..5]
```

Answer (score 2):

## shell (Linux)

```
basename `readlink /proc/$$/exe`
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java

```
import java.util.Random;
public class J {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random(-2134197984);
        String s = "";
        while (true) {
            int k = r.nextInt(27);
            if (k == 26) break;
            s += (char)('a' + k);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-print-hello-world) stackoverflow question.

Comment: How did you come up with exactly what seed to use?

Comment: @tbodt It's quite easy to build a generator that eventually will find if such a seed exists. In the same SO question, there's an answer about this, actually.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby (36)

```
# ruby -v|ruby -e"puts gets.split[0]"
```

Answer (score 1):

**BASH (39)**

```
bash --version | head -1 | cut -d, -f1
GNU bash
```

if bash is required output then its 55 chars

```
bash --version | head -1 | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d" " -f2
bash
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

Both of these include the "Script" part of JavaScript as a string literal. Could someone suggest a way to derive that part from the DOM when no script elements exist in the document?

#### [JavaScript was named after Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#History) (77)

```
for(i in navigator)i[4]=='E'&&alert(i[0].toUpperCase()+i.slice(1,4)+'Script')
```

#### Script elements have a "language" attribute (218, works in Chrome/Safari only)

```
u=123;for(w=l=97;w<u;++w)for(x=l;x<u;++x)for(y=l;y<u;++y)for(z=l;z<u;document.write('<script language="'+n+'script">this._?alert(n[_=0].toUpperCase()+n.slice(1)+"Script"):_=1</script>'))n=String.fromCharCode(w,x,y,z++)
```

Answer (score 1):

**VBScript**

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
msgbox split(fso.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).Type," ")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 25

The following should be in a file named `c.c`

```
main(){puts(__FILE__+2);}
```

alternate version, 27 chars:

```
main(){putchar(*__FILE__);}
```

Comment: Not sure this counts... the resulting C code contains the character 'c'.

Comment: Put in a file named 'C' if your compiler will accept files with no extensions.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript/ECMAScript – 31, <del>35</del>, <del>57</del>

```
for(i in{ECMAScript:0})alert(i)
```

<sub>located in `JavaScript.html`, or `ECMAScript.html`:</sub>

<del>`alert(location.href.substr(-15,10))`</del>

<del>`document.write(window.location.pathname.substr(-15, 10));`</del>

Answer (score 1):

### Python (27)

```
print str(copyright)[24:30]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (win32)

#### 68 characters

```
>>> import sys;print str.upper(sys.executable[12])+sys.executable[13:18]
'Python'
```

#### 41 characters

```
>>> print __import__('sys').executable[12:18]
'python'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Groovy ( JVM language )**

```
def a =  Closure.class.name​​​​​​​​​
6.times { print a[it] }
```

Which prints `groovy` as output :D

Comment: How about `println Closure.class.name.tokenize('.')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

### R, 11 chars

```
LETTERS[18]
```

Alternatively 54 characters, using a non custom environment variable:

```
strsplit(packageDescription("base")$Author,"")[[1]][1]
```

Comment: 18 isn't a system variable or something, is it?

Comment: No, it is the eighteenth letter of the ISO basic Latin alphabet! ;-)

Comment: The name of the language can only be invoked indirectly, i.e., from non custom environment variables, built-in functions or methods or the interpreter/compiler of the language.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 25

```
main(){printf("%X",12);}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Smalltalk** Squeak/Pharo flavour **16** chars

```
self environment
```

In Smalltalk, the name of global name space is Smalltalk

Answer (score 1):

## dc

Noticed this was missing so here's

```
Od*dP1-P
```

Comment: It needs one more 'd', like so: `Od*dP1-P`

Answer (score 1):

## php

Very late but php have more way to show itself.

```
ob_start();
phpcredits();
$c=ob_get_clean();
echo substr($c,0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RU2kA/1/

Code should be run from a html page enclosed within the `script` tag that has a `type` attribute

```
var x = document.querySelector("script");alert(x.type.split("/")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js: 29 characters

```javascript
console.log(process.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java

```
class j {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.out.print(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(43392).toString().substring(0,4));
    }
}
```

The Character constant referenced is the Unicode block of Javanese, which contains the aksara Jawa characters traditionally used for writing the Javanese language. :)

Comment: Don't forget to explain how your answer works (in your answer).

Comment: @Quincunx Thanks for the recommendation, added explaination.

Answer (score 0):

### **C#**

```
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CSharpCodeProvider).Name.Substring(0,6));
```

Comment: That would print `CSharp`, though, which is only an approximation of the name used in contexts that won't allow `#`, such as identifiers or Wikipedia.

Comment: Hey! I see a "CSharp" in your source code!

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby(35)

Using the RUBY_DESCRIPTION variable may be cheating a little, but I'm not using the string "ruby" at least.

```
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: You don't need the (' ')

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (24-25)

25 with Bash:

```
a=`php -v`&&echo ${a:0:3}
```

24 if we can omit `<?php`:

```
echo substr(__FILE__,-3)
```

Comment: Is first example a real solution?

Comment: @Alexandru Yup.

Comment: Contain php literally - doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 52

```
main=putStr$map(enumFrom 'G'!!)[1,26,44,36,30,37,37]
```

Could be shorter if the answer can be case insensitive. I chose to start at `'G'` because Haskell has no G's in its name, and `'G'` comes before `'H'` using `enumFrom`. This solution does not define anything other than `main`.

Answer (score 0):

**Java**

```
public class Me {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(System.class.toString().substring(6, 7).toUpperCase() + System.class.toString().substring(7, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a code golf, so we like to see the whole File, please. Does it, by any chance, contain the word `Java`?

Comment: Looks absolutely fine

Comment: A working solution. It prints 'Java', extracted from the System class' package declaration, but there's definitely room for improvement regarding code length.

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 21 chars

```
[H|_]=pre_loaded(),H.
```

Run in the interactive shell.  This works in R14B02 but I don't know if the Erlang module will always be first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

### Objective-C - 151 Chars

Little bit of trickery by taking the class name of NSObject, and chopping off the 'NS'

```
id s=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSObject class]];
[s deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];NSLog(@"%@%c%c%c%c%c",s,105,118,101,45,67);
```

Comment: 105,118,101,45,67 aren't system variables - are they?

Comment: @userunknown they are the ascii codes of "ive-c". disqualify or not?

Answer (score 0):

## Element, 30 characters

```
2'116 110[2:1-+'101"]7'69[,#`]
```

Element is a language of my own design. For some limited documentation, you can look [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/sum-of-positive-integers-spoj-sizecon#5268). For the source to an Element interpreter written in Perl, you can look [here](http://pastebin.com/rZKMKDWv).

Here is a walkthrough of how it works:

```
2` stores a 2 onto the control stack for later use
116 110 push those values (t and n) onto the stack
[ start a for loop that is repeated twice
   2: duplicate the 110
   1-+ adds a negative one to the top copy of 110
   ' move the top copy to the control stack as temporary storage
   101 add the code for an e onto the stack
   " move the copy from the control stack back on top of the 101 
] end the for loop, this loops takes advantage of the fact that n m l are in consecutive order and both have an e in between 
7' push a 7 onto the control stack
69 push the code for an E onto the stack
[ start a for loop that executes 7 times
   , perform ->char / ->num conversion
   # throws away the top item on the stack since this is the item->num conversion
   ` pop and output the top item on the stack, since this is the needed item->char conversion
] end the for loop, which prints out the numbers in character form in reverse order, to spell "Element".
```

Answer (score 0):

## Q (6 chars)

```
10h$81
```

Answer (score 0):

### bc

```
ipv4=$(ipmaddr show lo ipv4 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}') && echo "ibase=10;obase=16;"$(echo "ibase=6;$((2**${#ipv4}))" | bc) | bc
```

Let's deconstruct it:

```
ipmaddr show lo ipv4
1:  lo
    inet  224.0.0.1
```

result is unexpected, I expected 127.0.0.1, but 224.0.0.1 is sufficient.

- `tail -n1` takes the last line.
- `awk '{print $2}'` only the ip, so **ipv4=224.0.0.1** now.
- `${#ipv4}` is the length of this String which is 9 (our magic number :) )
- `$((2**${#ipv4}))` 2^9 is 512 as we all know.
- `echo "ibase=6;$((2**${#ipv4})) | bc` interprets 512 as a number to the base 6, which is 188 in decimal
- `echo "ibase=10;obase=16;"188 | bc` converts it to hexadecimal, which is - surprise:

> bc

Note: A shorter solution should be

```
 echo "ibase=6;obase=16;512" | bc
```

for the right part of the &&, but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 39 chars

```
main(){putchar(2[(char*)strerror(0)]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## F♯  - 187 Char

I had some fun with this - even if it's not really golfed. I should come up with a cleverer way to obscure the 72 and 2 though

```
let a="It's like OCaml... But .net!"|>Seq.sumBy(fun a->System.Convert.ToInt32(a))
System.Console.Write(System.Convert.ToChar(a%72*2))
System.Console.Write(System.Convert.ToChar(a%72))
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, obvious golfed solution

```
main(){putchar(67);}
```

Of course, it's not quite as short as the [J version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1138).

Answer (score 0):

### SQL <s>33</s> 32

```
print substring(@@version,11, 3)
```

(tested with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 19

Less perlish than the other perl answer, but shorter.

```
print substr $^X,-4
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell 137

This uses a fairly interesting method of encoding strings. Thought I'd share it.

```
import Data.Char
main=
  (print. map chr . reverse . map last . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (\x->zipWith subtract x$tail x))[50,-14,-31,-20,-7,0,108]
```

Bonus points to anyone who can explain why this works.

Comment: For those seeking enlightenment. I explain the formula here: http://www.walpenprod.com/obfuscating-strings/

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
<?php 
//first option use something that probably isn't available in windows installs
print substr($_SERVER['_'],-3) . "\n";

// this should work everywhere
print strtolower(substr(array_pop(array_filter(array_keys($_SERVER),'filterSELF')),0,3)) . "\n";
// uses the following function to filter out only 'PHP_SELF'
function filterSELF($toCheck){
    return (strlen($toCheck) == 8 && substr($toCheck,-5) == '_SELF');
}
```

both return php

Answer (score 0):

### Nemerle, 57

```
Nemerle.IO.print(typeof(Option).FullName.Substring(0,7));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```python
import sys
try: from StringIO import StringIO
except: from io import StringIO # py3
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = s = StringIO()
import this # yeah
sys.stdout = stdout
print(s.getvalue()[11:17])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 36 characters

```
(subseq(package-name *package*)0 11)
=> "COMMON-LISP"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

```
print$^X=~/([a-z]+)$/,$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol

```
copy/part at system/license 16 5
```

For Rebol 2 use:

```
copy/part at system/license 1 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl, 28**

```
print @a=(a..z)[15,4,17,11];
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Molecule](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/molecule), 2 bytes

```
;M
```

Pre-defined variables are awesome.

Comment: This ain't no codegolf, son.

Comment: @cat I know.
I'm still adding the byte count just because.

Answer (score 0):

## Factor

Works always:

```
version-info " " split first print
```

The hacky way:

```
(command-line) first "." split >title print
```

All Factor source files end in `.factor`, so this just gets that and titlecases it. Won't work for compiled executables, probably.

Answer (score -1):

### C#, lots of characters

```
class g
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var r = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
        System.Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.GetLanguageFromExtension(r.Substring(r.Length - 2, 2)).ToUpper());
    }
}
```

That's probably closer to the spirit of the problem, but this will also work, hard coding the file extension, and is probably still effectively following the guidelines:

```
class g
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.GetLanguageFromExtension(".cs").ToUpper());
    }
}
```

Comment: I read `CSharp.CSharp`

Answer (score -1):

### iX2Web

```
**iX2001C3 934238Mwlp WDJXZWJ8Xz AJMA0K=*
```

Answer (score -1):

## Go

This generates an indirect language name, i.e. Issue 9 (hey, it's not directly said - you need to know what this refers to). I think it's a valid name for Go, considering it has redirect on Wikipedia. For more information why Issue 9 is a valid name, please see https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=9.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Issue 9")
}
```

Comment: This is entertaining. It *is* a popcon, after all.

Answer (score -2):

### Java

```
System.out.println("".getClass().getName().substring(0, 4));
```

:D

Comment: Already given months ago (in a more verbose style). Beside, your code won't compile as is...

Answer (score -3):

## PHP - 22/14

(assumes a file named 'php')

```
<?php echo __FILE__;?>
```

Down to 14 with short tags

```
<?=__FILE__;?>
```

And then

```
php ./php
```

Comment: file name is cheating, surely?

Comment: Looking at the rules I believe I am well within the guidelines.

Answer (score -5):

### Javascript : 48

```
alert((function Javascript(){}+"").substr(9,10))
```

Comment: That contains the test "Javascript."