# Write a program to print the sum of the ascii codes of the program

Tags: code-challenge, self-referential

Your task is to write a program to print the sum of the ASCII codes of the characters of the program itself. You are not allowed to open any file (Any input such as command line arguments, standard input or files is prohibited).

The program that prints the lowest number (i.e. has the lowest sum of ASCII codes) wins.

Here is an example (not the shortest) of such a program  written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("4950");/*i*/
return 0;
}
```

(no new line after `}`)

Comment: It'd be interesting to see a quine solution: one that produces and sums its own bytes.

Comment: Not very challenging imho. It can be trivially brute-forced, especially for languages that simply dump tokens, such as PowerShell, Golfscript, etc.

Comment: Might have been a bit more interesting to have the program open itself and manually sum/print the characters.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. It's an easy question which, as Joey guessed, was meant to be brute forced, but judging by the number of answers people seem to like it.

Comment: I downvoted and the comment gives the reason, why. As I have noted before, [I don't consider the number of answers an indication of quality](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/941761#941761). Just because it can be easily solved does not make this an interesting or even challenging challenge. My opinion, at least.

Comment: Wait. What? On one hand you complain that the question is easy and not interesting and then you downvote me (-2 for me). On the other hand you post 25% of answers on this question (+70 for you).

Comment: So you see this as a reputation battle? Fine, I can easily change my answers to CW. In a way the large number of answers was a bit of a protest and to show that it's trivial to churn out lots of answers. Compare this for example to the task that wanted the alphabet four times. Also my answering self (bound to the task specifications) and my commenting self (hoping to improve general site quality) are often fairly separate. Anyway, happier now that I deleted them? They were still valid answers, though.

Comment: I think the title should be changed to say "compute *and* print".

Comment: I love how the example program exhibits undefined behavior. That is, there is no newline at the end of the file.

Comment: @trinithis: I don't think it's undefined behavior. Can you point to a reference (best would be standard section)? It's related with the fact that #include doesn't add extra new line at the end.

Comment: It actually applies for non-empty source files. The C++ standard says it in 2.1.1.2 (Phases of translation). C says it in 5.1.1.1.2.3 (Translation phases). C simply mandates it. C++ says you would otherwise get undefined behavior. I just googled "c99 standard" and "c++ standard" and took a look at the drafts there (should be first pdf search results).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### wc, prints 0

Someone said "cat-like languages", so...

An empty file:

Execute with `wc -c file.wc`. At 0 bytes, I think this is the winner in the 'not really a programming language' category.

Also

### cat, prints 80 (base 13)

```
80
```

No terminating newline, the number 80<sub>13</sub> is equivalent to 104 in decimal. You can go shorter with 60<sub>17</sub> (102 dec), but I figured "base 13" would be worth more geek points.

EDIT: New `wc` example, this one can be run as a program.

```
#!/usr/bin/wc
ÿÿzw17
```

(As encoded in Latin-1 - the ÿ is a byte with value 255)

Sum of bytes is 2223, output is:

```
  2  2 23 ./w
```

Comment: But wc should read a file, containing a 0-byte to produce Number 0, not an empty one. Empty is not Null.

Comment: user: One might argue that the sum of values in an empty set is still 0. Nevertheless, `wc -c` is forbidden in the question anyway.

Comment: The only clause which seems to do so is "Any input such as command line arguments ... is prohibited" so leave off the -c, then it prints `0 0 0` (if the file being passed as a file prohibits it, then all scripting languages are also forbidden)

Comment: +1 for `wc`, -1 for base cheating, +1 for making jokes in base 13.

Comment: I would say `wc` is an application, not a language.

Comment: You could do `10` in base 97.

Comment: @userunknown `$ >file` will create a 0-byte file by overwriting (or creating) its contents with the output of nothing

Comment: @B1KMusic: The program, as I understand it, would be `wc -c file.wc` and that should be the content of the file file.wc, if it is the program. It would not be empty.

Comment: @userunknown yes, I was adding to your point, `>test && wc -c test` outputs `0 test`

Answer (score 14):

### PHP, m4, and other cat-like languages: 150

```
150
```

Found this solution using a simple Haskell program to brute-force it:

```
f :: String -> Bool
f s = (read s :: Int) == (sum . map fromEnum) s

main = mapM_ print [filter f $ sequence $ replicate n ['0'..'9'] | n <- [1..10]]
```

Comment: I guess this is the absolute shortest.

Comment: @Alexandru: Not necessarily.  There may be program that is one or two characters long that correctly prints the sum using some built-in functions, say like `5!` in J.

Comment: @mellamokb The sum of the ASCII characters in `5!` is 86, not 125.

Comment: @Peter: Indeed, I was showing an example of the *type* of solution that might be smaller than 150, but not an actual solution. I haven't found one yet (and btw, 5! is 120, not 125) :-)

Answer (score 12):

### Brainf*ck, 255

```
-.¤
```

This will not print the number 255, but rather the 255th ASCII character.

This might be considered cheating because the BF compiler skips over the `¤`.

Comment: Tim: The lowest number wins, not the shortest program. In any case, I don't think the `¤` is cheating, as it's just a normal comment.

Comment: You get a lower score by substracting a little bit more: ----.␦

Answer (score 9):

### Javascript, prints <s>9432</s> 6902

```
(function a(){b="("+a+")()";c=0;for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){c+=b.charCodeAt(i-0)}alert(c)})()
```

This is the first quine solution so far, unless I am not understanding the [Haskell one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/write-a-program-to-print-the-sum-of-the-ascii-codes-of-the-program/2930#2930) correctly.

Comment: That Haskell code is just searching for the smallest number which will equal the sum of its digit's ASCII codes. I guess most answers here were done by brute-force.

Comment: Can be reduced further from 89 to 86 bytes with: `(function a(){b="("+a+")()";for(i=c=0;i<b.length;i++)c+=b.charCodeAt(i-0);alert(c)})()`

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell

```
((310))
```

prints 310.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 500

```
say     500
```

There are two tabs between `say` and `500`. :)

(Run as a one-liner with `perl -E`, as far as I can tell this is within the rules)

Comment: I like the 2 tabs

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, prints 380

```
p (380)
```

No trailing newline after the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell

```
(230)
```

prints 230, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell

```
-(-320)
```

prints 320.

Answer (score 5):

### J, 150

```
?!6
```

With the caveat that it will be correct only 1/720th of the time.

Comment: Random on factorial 6? Hmmm, I don't think so, Tim.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, prints 781

```
print  781
```

Two spaces.

Comment: I especially like the 2 spaces.

Answer (score 4):

## Element, 220

This is a language of my own creation, and it is documented on my answer to another question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/sum-of-positive-integers-spoj-sizecon#5268).

```
220`!
```

Here is a walkthrough of how it works: The `220` pushes that number onto the stack. Then the `` ` `` outputs the top element of the stack. The `!` then performs a logical NOT on the control stack (a separate stack), setting it to 1.

Answer (score 4):

### INTERCAL, 1572

I can't believe no one's done INTERCAL yet!

```
DOREADOUT#1572


DOGIVEUP
```

(Includes terminating newline.) This program prints out MDLXXII.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, prints 4440

```
<?php
for($x=0;$x<15000;$x++)if($x==4440){printf($x);exit;}
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, prints 3902

```
&{[char[]]$myinvocation.Line|%{$s+=+$_};$s}
```

Looks into the line currently run and sums the code point values.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 1700

Strange - nobody posted a C solution yet (excluding the example in the question).

```
main(R){puts("1700");}
```

No newline at the end.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 198

```
33*6
```

and

```
6*33
```

Found it by brute force. In J there are no 1 or 2 char solutions, and the only 3-char solution is `150`. Barring any bugs in my search, there are no other 4-char solutions, either.

---

From the #jsoftware IRC channel, we also had `<.%:10!20` at 429 and a self-counting quine `+/a.i.2#(,{:)'+/a.i.2#(,{:)'''` at 1706.

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), score <s>777</s> 333

```
3a
3o
```

I think this is allowed.

The newline is normalized to `\r\n` by the naz interpreter at runtime, a sequence which contributes **23** to the overall score.

**Explanation**

```
3a # Add 3 to the register
3o # Output 3 times
```

The previous solution:

```
7a2o1m1o1a
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, prints 690

```
die 690 . $/
```

Or, if we can post one-liners (`perl -E`)

```
say(570)
```

Prints 570.

(No trailing newlines)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <del>1750 900 860</del> 790

`alert(790)`

(Carriage return (CR, `\r` or `\x0D`) after or before the program)

These programs are found by brute-forcing.

Bigger values:

```
alert(860)%0
alert(900)&&6
document.write(1750)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java -128

I know reading stdin isn't allowed but I wanted to provide an example of how I calculated my score.

My code sums the ASCII count of itself passed on stdin and prints out -128

```
class P{public static void main(String[]z)throws Exception{byte v=0;int b=0;while((b=System.in.read())!=-1){v+=(byte)b;}System.out.println(v);}}
```

No trailing new line

Comment: I think your sum is overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, prints 300

```
p   300
```

There is a space and a tab between the `p` and the `300`. No trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch files, 500

```
ECHO  500
```

As well, notice the two spaces between "ECHO" (uppercase on purpose) and "500".

Answer (score 1):

## K (<s>923 796 795 746</s> 513)

I'm not sure if this falls afoul of the rules or not. It doesn't use stdin, it opens itself as a vector of bytes and sums.

```
+/1:.z.f
```

Usage:

```
q scriptname.k
```

edit 2012.05.08 - no need to hsym the file handle
2012.05.09 - saved 1 point by converting to byte instead of int

2012.05.17 -  Can save a load of points by reading file as bytestream rather than text:

Answer (score 1):

## Lenguage, 4 bytes, prints 0

Source code consists of 4 null bytes. Therefore, it should output (0+0+0+0)=0.

Comment: Wow. For once, Lenguage wins (and has a golfing chance).

Answer (score 0):

#### bc 1160

invoked with echo and blanks, the whole String, including 7 blanks, `echo 1160    |  bc` has a bytesum of 1160.

```
echo 1160    |  bc
```

150 works for bc too:

```
echo "150" > 150
bc -q 150
150
```

Answer (score 0):

### D, 9752

this one actually calculates it similar to my [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/2987#2987)

```
enum c=q{import std.stdio;void main(){int s;foreach(d;"enum c=q{"~c~"};mixin(c);")s+=d;write(s);}};mixin(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Whitespace, 369

This 20-character program prints the number 369, which is the sum of the ascii values of its characters (which are Tab,Space,Linefeed characters, here symbolized by T,S,L, respectively):

```
SSSTSTTTSSSTLTLSTLLL
```

(369 = 7*9 + 8*32 + 5*10, there being 7 Tabs, 8 Spaces, and 5 Linefeeds.)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 7518

A small modification of my [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good):

```
main=print.sum.map fromEnum$q++show q;q="main=print.sum.map fromEnum$q++show q;q="
```

Answer (score 0):

### Brainf*ck, 253 (or 252)

Slight improvement on Peter Olson's solution:

```
---.H
```

Provided non-printables are allowed, it can be improved further by adding a `-` and replacing `H` by ASCII code 26.

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 1090 bytes

```scala
println (1090)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 5440

Highest score wins, right?

```
import sys
print sum(ord(i)for i in open(sys.argv[0]).read())
```

I just thought I'd post it anyway b/c it's a halfway quine solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure - 8008

There's only a handful of quines so far, and clojure's not represented, so I figured I'd give it a go:

```
(let[s"(let[s%s](apply +(map int(format s(pr-str s)))))"](apply +(map int(format s(pr-str s)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes (300)

```
C25LO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2cjUx9/2vxKYVjrcDmQDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score 198

```r
6*33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwEEX3PcVQF8nULqwFsYUewL0XKDE1UzUpyRTx9LHRIriYgff5H56P8VDUddwoo9UN2PQMxCKAct5rxW02ebIsw/yQMw/HszstlKdNjohZtg6fRrPRHtLT0KezL3CfrNru4UJXYgjuPjM5G0D@ilYwttngvCQgC1XbYIJxhQZpkFSMXfevMPWB9U5SOZaiEIsKfkVVihDjGw)

[TIO](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwEEX3PcVQF8nULqwFsYUewL0XKDE1UzUpyRTx9LHRIriYgff5H56P8VDUddwoo9UN2PQMxCKAct5rxW02ebIsw/yQMw/HszstlKdNjohZtg6fRrPRHtLT0KezL3CfrNru4UJXYgjuPjM5G0D@ilYwttngvCQgC1XbYIJxhQZpkFSMXfevMPWB9U5SOZaiEIsKfkVVihDjGw) link includes the code used to find this solution, which is the only 1+2 digit solution possible using the "`*`" operator.
Of, course, after finding this, I searched all the other answers for the string "`6*33`", which revealed that [AlliedEnvy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23147/95126) discovered the same solution in J 6 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), score 354

```
|?|+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%3F%7C%2B&i=)

`|?` returns the program's source. `|+` sums it.

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, 6 bytes, score 333

```bash
<<<333
```

`<` = 60, `3` = 51, so it adds up to a nice expression.