# Linear Function Solver from Two Points (x,y)

Tags: code-golf

## The Task

Write a function L() that takes two Tuple arguments of coordinates in the form (x, y), and returns their respective linear function in the form (a, c), where a is the co-efficent of the x term and c is the y-intercept.

You can assume that the input will not be a line perpendicular the the x axis, and that the two inputs are separate points.

## Scoring

This is Code Golf: shortest program wins.

Please Note: No use of any mathematical functions apart from basic operators (+,-,/,*).

## Example

Here is my un-golfed solution in Python.

```
def L(Point1, Point2):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    Gradient = (float(Point1[y]) - float(Point2[y])) / (float(Point1[x]) - float(Point2[x]))
    YIntercept = Point1[y] - Gradient * Point1[x] 
    return (Gradient, YIntercept)
```

Output:

```
>>> L( (0,0) , (1,1) )
(1.0, 0.0)

>>> L( (0,0) , (2,1) )
(0.5, 0.0)

>>> L( (0,0) , (7,1) )
(0.14285714285714285, 0.0)

>>> L( (10,22.5) , (5,12.5) )
(2.0, 2.5)
```

Comment: `L( (0,0) , (0,1) )`?

Comment: You can assume that the input is not a line parallel to the X axis.

Comment: *You can assume that the input is not a line parallel to the X axis.* Do you mean Y axis?

Comment: Sorry, the edit on the post was correct, perpendicular to the X axis.

Comment: `L((0,0),(0,0))`?

Comment: You guys are so good at digging holes... Two inputs must be different.

Comment: This is extremely close to being a cut-down version of [Shamir's secret-sharing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1230/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor This is also close to being a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5429/rosetta-stone-challenge-find-the-rule-for-a-series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## J - 23 char

Fairly straightforward. Defines a dyadic verb `L` to be used as `(x1,y1) L (x2,y2)`.

```
L=:%~/@:-,-/@(*|.)%-&{.
```

Explanation:

```
L=:%~/@:-,-/@(*|.)%-&{.  NB. the function L
                    &{.  NB. x coord of both points
                   -     NB. left x minus right x
             ( |.)       NB. flip right argument: (y2,x2)
              *          NB. pointwise multiplication of (x1,y1) and (y2,x2)
          -/@            NB. subtract the two results: (x1*y2)-(y1*x2)
                  %      NB. divide: (x1*y2 - y1*x2)/(x1-x2)
        -                NB. pointwise subtraction
   %~/@:                 NB. divide y difference by x diff: (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
         ,               NB. append results together
L=:                      NB. assign function to L
```

Examples:

```
   L=:%~/@:-,-/@(*|.)%-&{.
   0 0 L 1 1
1 0
   0 0 L 2 1
0.5 0
   0 0 L 7 1
0.142857 0
   10 22.5 L 5 12.5
2 2.5
   0 0 L 0 1  NB. __ is negative infinity
__ 0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [GNU dc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <strike>30</strike> 24 bytes

```
[sysxly-rlx-/dlx*lyr-]sL
```

Defines a macro `L` such that
(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) should be pushed to the stack in that order before calling, and after calling `L`, (a, c) may be popped from the stack (in reverse order of course - it is a stack).

#### Testcase (save as "linear.dc" and run `dc linear.dc`):

```
[sysxly-rlx-/dlx*lyr-]sL   # Define L macro

10                         # Push x1 to the stack
22.5                       # Push y1 to the stack
5                          # Push x2 to the stack
12.5                       # Push y2 to the stack

lLx                        # Call L macro
f                          # Dump the stack
```

Output is:

```
$ dc linear.dc 
2.5
2
$
```

#### Explanation of L macro:

- `sy` pop y<sub>2</sub> to `y` register
- `sx` pop x<sub>2</sub> to `x` register
- `ly` push `y` register (y<sub>2</sub>)
- `-` subtract y<sub>2</sub> from y<sub>1</sub>
- `r` swap (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) and x<sub>1</sub> on stack
- `lx` push `x` register (x<sub>2</sub>)
- `-` subtract x<sub>2</sub> from x<sub>1</sub>
- `/` divide (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) by (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>) to get gradient
- `d` duplicate gradient
- `lx` push `x` register (x<sub>2</sub>)
- `*` multiply (x<sub>2</sub>) by gradient
- `ly` push `y` register (y<sub>2</sub>)
- `r` swap (y<sub>2</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub> * gradient) on stack
- `-` subtract (x<sub>2</sub> * gradient) from (y<sub>2</sub>)

Comment: Thanks, not bad. I admit to being beaten. ;)

Comment: @m.buettner Re-golfed and re-explained.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 41 characters

```
f(x,y)(u,v)=(a,y-a*x)where a=(y-v)/(x-u)
```

Not a lot to golf here. It's pretty much what you'd write normally minus whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>55</s> 38 bytes

<s>This was surprisingly long (those pesky long function names...)</s> **EDIT:** Changed the approach for the axis intercept (taking some inspiration from the OP's own answer). It turns out calculating it directly wasn't the most clever idea.

```
L={g=1/Divide@@(#2-#),#[[2]]-g#[[1]]}&
```

Use like

```
L[{10,22.5},{5,12.5}]
> {2., 2.5}
```

Thanks to Mathematica you can also obtain the general result:

```
L[{r,s},{p,q}]
> {(p - r)/(q - s), (q r - p s)/(q - s)}
```

(This last example shows how I had originally implemented this.)

Just for the record

```
L[{0,0},{0,1}]
> {ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate}
```

which is technically correct.

Comment: Ahh, Awesome, I had a bit of a mind black figuring that out, I'll blame it on my tiredness

Comment: +1.  Why `ComplexInfinity` and not plain old `Infinity`? *(I don't know Mathematica)*

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I think it's because, without explicitly telling Mathematica that it can work in reals, it always assumes the the space in question to be complex numbers, so as not to throw away complex solutions of real equations.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, <s>62</s> 48

Thanks to @Michael for golfing it down with ES 6.

```js
L=(a,b)=>[s=(b[1]-a[1])/(b[0]-a[0]),a[1]-s*a[0]]
```

Old version:

```js
function L(a,b){return[s=(b[1]-a[1])/(b[0]-a[0]),a[1]-s*a[0]]}
```

Sample input:

```js
L([0,0],[7,1])
```

Sample output:

```js
[0.14285714285714285, 0]
```

For the record:

```js
L([0,0],[0,1])
[Infinity, NaN]
```

Comment: 46 using ES6 : `L=(a,b)=>[g=(p=a[1]-b[1])/(q=a[0]-b[0]),p-g*q]`

Comment: @Michael Cool. I am sort of a JS newbie, so I didn't know you could do that. Thanks.

Comment: @m.buettner You're right... Fixed

Comment: Now all answers are exactly ten characters apart. :D

Comment: Awww. The bunny changed!

Answer (score 2):

### C# 105 bytes

This is isn't just the function and will compile completely on it's own. I had put `L` in the `System` namespace to shorting the using, but it's better to fully qualify and save on using a namespace. Saved the brackets. Also a saving from `return new z[]` into `return new[]`

```c#
using z=System.Single;class P{z[] L(z[]a,z[]b){z c=(a[1]-b[1])/(a[0]-b[0]);return new[]{c,a[1]-c*a[0]};}}
```

Comment: Is `(c*a[0])` necessary? Can't you eliminate those parenthesis and save 2 bytes?

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, thanks. While c# doesn't use BODMAS the multiplication will be done first (I think).

Comment: I'd say you have to include the `namespace` declaration, or change it to `System.Single`, for this solution to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3 (51)

```python
def L(p,q):x,y=p;X,Y=q;m=(Y-y)/(X-x);return m,y-x*m
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua 5.1.4: <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```
function L(q,w)a=(q[2]-w[2])/(q[1]-w[1])return a,q[2]-a*q[1];end
```

Example Usage:

```
> print(L( {0,0}, {1,0} ))
-0   0
> print(L( {0,0}, {1,1} ))
1    0
> print(L( {0,0}, {7,1} ))
0.14285714285714    0
> print(L( {0,0}, {0,1} ))
-inf   -nan
> print(L( {0,0}, {0,0} ))
-nan   -nan
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 88 (was 106)

Improved: thanks for your comments.

```
struct t{double x,y;};
t L(t u, t v){u.x=(v.y-u.y)/(v.x-u.x);u.y=v.y-u.x*v.x;return u;}
```

Golfed:

```
typedef struct T{double x,y;}t;
t line(t u, t v){t z;z.x=(v.y-u.y)/(v.x-u.x);z.y=v.y-(z.x*v.x);return z;}
```

Source

```
typedef struct T{
    double x,y;
} t;

t line(t u, t v)
{
t z;
z.x=(v.y-u.y)/(v.x-u.x);
z.y=v.y-(z.x*v.x);
return z;
}
```

Comment: I see an unnecessary space ;)

Comment: If it is C++, why the `typedef`?

Comment: Also, I think you can get rid of `z`: `u.x=(v.y-u.y)/(v.x-u.x); u.y=v.y-z.x*v.x; return u;`

Answer (score 1):

## Apple Swift <s>95</s> 86

*This may be the first Swift entry on PCG.SE??*

```
func L(x:Float...)->(Float,Float){var a=(x[3]-x[1])/(x[2]-x[0]);return(a,x[1]-a*x[0])}
```

I don't see this language being a huge hit to the Code Golf community.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 - <strike>64</strike> 57 Bytes

```
def L(q,w):a=(q[1]-w[1])/(q[0]-w[0]);return a,q[1]-a*q[0]
```

You can get it down to 43 if you don't use Tuple, which many people are doing...

```
def L(x,y,q,w):a=(x-q)/(y-w);return a,y-a*x
```

Comment: `return(a,q[1]-a*q[0])`

Comment: @ace Thanks, that was sloppy

Answer (score 0):

#### Golfscript: 25 bytes

```
~:y\:x;-\x--1?*.x-1**y+\p
```

Since the function needs to be named 'L', I saved it as 'L.gs' locally.

The catch, as explained by @Dennis in [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/tips-for-golfing-in-golfscript), is that we need to trick Golfscript into using rational numbers instead of integers. So this works if you're willing to accept input `X1 Y1 X2 Y2` *in golfscript notation*

```
# L( (0,0) , (1,1) )
echo "0 0 1 1" | golfscript L.gs
> 1/1
> 0/1
#L( (10,22.5) , (5,12.5) )
echo "10 22 2-1?+ 5 12 2-1?+" | golfscript L.gs
> 2/1
> 5/2
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby – 48 characters

Nearly identical to the JavaScript answer:

```
L=->u,v{a,b,c,d=*u,*v;[s=(d-b).fdiv(c-a),b-s*a]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (75 chars)

```
function L($u,$v){return[$s=($v[1]-$u[1])/($v[0]-$u[0]),$v[1]-($s*$v[0])];}
```

test : `print_r(L([0,0],[7,1]));`

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.14285714285714
    [1] => 0
)
```

(thanks @ace)