# Can you Meta Quine?

Tags: code-golf, quine

Similar to other quine puzzles (more specifically, [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2582/3862)), write a program that produces the source for itself.

**Here's the new twist:** The code produced should *NOT* be identical to the source. Rather, it should output a different program that will create the first.

The challenge linked to above achieved that by jumping between two languages. I'm thinking this one would be done in **just one language**, but the two (or more) versions of the source should be significantly different (see rules below). With this constraint, [single character answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2593/3862) would be disallowed, thus requiring a little more thought be put into a final submission.

---

**RULES**

1. Your code must be produced in just one language. (Multiple submissions, one for each language is perfectly acceptable.)
2. Your different code versions must be syntactically distinct. In other words, if you were to draw out an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for your code, there should be at least one node different.

   - Supplying an **AST** will not be necessary, but if you feel inclined to provide one for each of your programs, it *would* help in judging.
3. You may produce as many iterations as you wish, as long as they all remain syntactically distinct. (More will help your score, see below.)

---

**SCORING**

Your final score will be the mean length of all your programs, divided by the number of programs.

Example 1:

> A (source for B) = 50 characters
>   B (source for A) = 75 characters
>   Final Score = **31.25**

Example 2:

> A (source for B) = 50 characters
>   B (source for C) = 75 characters
>   C (source for A) = 100 characters
>   Final Score = **25**

Comment: I meta quine once.

Comment: @mellamokb har har ;-)

Comment: This is actually just a more general version of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/create-a-rotating-quine) quine challenge, and the answers given there will win here, too.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the requirement for syntactic differences invalidates a 'rotating quine', so this is not more general.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was thinking this current form was enough, but if there is still disagreement about boothby's point, I do have an extra alternative constraints I can add.

Comment: Never meta quine I didn't like.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Python, 0 (limit of (68+3 *n* )/(16<sup>*n*</sup>))

If two abstract syntax trees are different if they have different constants,

```
r='r=%r;n=(0x%XL+1)%%0x10...0L;print r%%(r,n)';n=(0xF...FL+1)%0x10...0L;print r%(r,n)
```

there are 16<sup>*n*</sup> programs of length at most 68+3n, giving asymptotic score of 0.

If you want programs with variable structure, we can implement a binary adder on *n* bits.  Here, there are 2<sup>*n*</sup> programs of length *O*( *n*<sup>2</sup>).  Goes in a cycle due to dropped carry bit.

```
s="""
print 's='+'"'+'"'+'"'+s+'"'+'"'+'"'
n=lambda m:reduce(lambda (s,c),y:(s+(c^y,),c&y),m,((),1))[0]
print s[:112]
t=n(t)
print "t=(%s,)+(0,)*%s"%(t[0],len(t)-1)
for i in range(len(t)-1):
    print i*' '+'for i in range(2):'
    print ' '+i*' '+['pass','t=n(t)'][t[i+1]]
print s[113:-1]
"""

print 's='+'"'+'"'+'"'+s+'"'+'"'+'"'
n=lambda m:reduce(lambda (s,c),y:(s+(c^y,),c&y),m,((),1))[0]
print s[:112]
t=(0,)+(0,)*10
for i in range(2):
 t=n(t)
 for i in range(2):
  t=n(t)
  for i in range(2):
   t=n(t)
   for i in range(2):
    t=n(t)
    for i in range(2):
     pass
     for i in range(2):
      t=n(t)
      for i in range(2):
       pass
       for i in range(2):
        pass
        for i in range(2):
         pass
         for i in range(2):
          t=n(t)
t=n(t)
print "t=(%s,)+(0,)*%s"%(t[0],len(t)-1)
for i in range(len(t)-1):
    print i*' '+'for i in range(2):'
    print ' '+i*' '+['pass','t=n(t)'][t[i+1]]
print s[113:-1]
```

Comment: Might I be confused? It looks like the output is identical to the source (not the objective of this challenge)?

Comment: Look in the nested block.  `pass` will change to `t=n(t)` and back, in all 2^n combinations.

Comment: I do see that now. You confused me with all the repetition!

Comment: for some reason, I like very long golf solutions with tiny scores.

Comment: Wow, you completely owned that! Very nice.

Answer (score 6):

### C++, score of 0.734194

The following source code prints a meta quine of order 999 to the console (explanation below):

```
#define X 1*(1+1)
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define Q(S)auto q=#S;S
Q( \
  main() \
  { \
      using namespace std; \
      cout<<"#define X 1"; \
      int x=X==2?1000:X-1; \
      vector<int> factors; \
      for ( int p = 2; p <= x; ++p) \
      { \
        while ( x % p == 0 ) \
        { \
          factors.push_back( p ); \
          x /= p; \
        } \
      } \
      for ( int factor : factors ) \
      { \
        cout<<"*(1"; \
        for ( int i=1;i<factor;++i) \
          cout<<"+1"; \
        cout<<")"; \
      } \
      cout<<"\n#include<iostream>\n#include<vector>\n#define Q(S)auto q=#S;S\nQ("<<q<<")"; \
  })
```

The only line that changes is the first line. The value of `X` will be 1000, 999, 998, ..., 3, 2 and then it will start again. However, in order to get different syntax trees every time, `X` is represented in terms of its prime factorization, where every prime is written as a sum of `1`s. The ASTs are different, because the prime factorization of integers is different for every value.

The program will print itself, except that the first line is changed and the backslashes, line breaks and indentations that are within `Q(...)` will be removed.

The following program calculates the score of my answer:

```
#include <iostream>

const int n = 1000;

int getProgramLength( int n )
{
  int sum = 442;
  for ( int p = 2; p*p <= n; ++p )
  {
    while ( n % p == 0 )
    {
      sum += 2 * ( 1 + p );
      n /= p;
    }
  }
  if ( n > 1 )
    sum += 2 * ( 1 + n );
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  for ( int i = 2; i <= n; ++i )
    sum += getProgramLength( i );
  std::cout << (double)sum/(n-1)/(n-1) << '\n';
}
```

It printed 0.734194 to the console. Obviously, 1000 can be replaced by larger integers and the score will approach 0 as its limit. The mathematical proof involves Riemann's Zeta function is somewhat convoluted. I leave it as an exercise to the reader. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, score of 110.25

I have to admit, I'm not very good with quines. I'm 100% certain that there is room for improvement. The solution is based off of the same principle of the Element solution below.

The first program is 264 characters.

```
$s='$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;";$s=reverse$s;for(1..87){chop$s}$s=reverse$s;print$s;$f++;if($f==0){$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;$s"}';$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;";$s=reverse$s;for(1..87){chop$s}$s=reverse$s;print$s;$f++;if($f==0){$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;$s"}
```

The second program is 177 characters.

```
$s='$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;";$s=reverse$s;for(1..87){chop$s}$s=reverse$s;print$s;$f++;if($f==0){$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;$s"}';if($f==0){$a=chr(39);print"\$s=$a$s$a;$s"}
```

I'm working on the AST for this entry (and the Element entry).

---

## [Element](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5268/2867), score of 47.25

The first program is 105 characters.

```
\ \3\:\$\'\[\\\\\`\(\`\]\#\2\1\'\[\(\#\]\`\ \3\:\$\'\[\\\\\`\(\`\]\#\` 3:$'[\\`(`]#21'[(#]` 3:$'[\\`(`]#`
```

The second program is 84 characters.

```
\ \3\:\$\'\[\\\\\`\(\`\]\#\2\1\'\[\(\#\]\`\ \3\:\$\'\[\\\\\`\(\`\]\#\` 3:$'[\\`(`]#`
```

I'm sure that there is a lot of room for improvement.

In the first program there is one string (in which every character is escaped, despite a lot of redundancy) followed by executable parts A and B. Part A does several things: prints the string and escapes out of every character,  prints the last half of the string (which is the source for part B), and then prevents the part B that follows it from doing anything.

The second program is the same string followed by part B. Part B is based off of a simple quine; it prints a string preceded by an escaped version of it. This means it prints the string, and both parts A and B.

Comment: I think this definitively, beyond any doubt, proves the validity of Element as a programming language. It is so easy to use that I, so inexperienced that I have only managed to write one complete interpreter for Element, have been able to answer this question before any other person on this entire planet of 7,000,000,000 people. Element's "one character, one function, all the time"  paradigm  means that  all code is completely unambiguous. The language is versatile: except for `[]{}`, any command can be placed anywhere in the entire program without causing a syntax error. It is perfect.

Comment: A bit biased, are we? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### VBA: (251+216)/2/2 = 116.75

**251**

```vb
Sub a()
r=vbCrLf:c="If b.Lines(4, 4) = c Then"&r &"b.InsertLines 8, d"&r &"b.DeleteLines 4, 4"&r &"End If":d="b.InsertLines 6, c"&r &"b.DeleteLines 4, 2"
Set b=Modules("Q")
If b.Lines(4, 4) = c Then
b.InsertLines 8, d
b.DeleteLines 4, 4
End If
End Sub
```

**216**

```vb
Sub a()
r=vbCrLf:c="If b.Lines(4, 4) = c Then"&r &"b.InsertLines 8, d"&r &"b.DeleteLines 4, 4"&r &"End If":d="b.InsertLines 6, c"&r &"b.DeleteLines 4, 2"
Set b=Modules("Q")
b.InsertLines 6,c
b.DeleteLines 4,2
End Sub
```

This is run in **MSAccess** to make use of the `Module` object. The module is named `"Q"` for golfing. The difference in syntax comes from the `If ... Then` missing from the shorter version.

Comment: you can most likely get away with changing `vbCrLF` to `vbCr`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, <s>84.5</s> <s>64</s> 61

Two programs, both length <s>169</s> <s>128</s> 122.

```
(function c(){alert(/*
2/*/1/**/);return ('('+c+')()').replace(/\/([/\*])/,function(m,a){return a=='*'?'/\/':'/\*'});
})()
```

Before I golfed it, for your viewing pleasure:

```
(function c() {
    var r = /\/([/\*])/;
    var f = function(m, a) { return a === '*' ? '/\/' : '/\*' };
    var p = '(' + c + ')();';
    p = p.replace(r, f);
    /* This is just a comment!
    console.log('Quine, part two!'); /*/
    console.log('Quine, part one!'); /**/
    return p;
})();
```

Returns the new program and outputs the current part! <del>I could probably make it shorter without the function regex, but... I don't want to.</del>

Comment: No, they're syntatically distinct. Once you add the newlines, that is.

Answer (score 2):

## J - (24+30)/2 / 2 = 13.5 pts

Note that strings in J are not the backslash-escaped, but quote-escaped à la Pascal: `'I can''t breathe!'`.

```
30$(,5#{.)'''30$(,5#{.)'         NB. program 1, 24 char
'30$(,5#{.)''''''30$(,5#{.)'''   NB. program 2, 30 char
```

Program 1 has AST `noun verb hook noun` and program 2 has AST `noun`. Program 2 is a quoted version of program 1, which will just return program 1 when run, so this method can't be extended to three copies that easily :P

Program 1 operates by taking a copy of the code portion of the source, with a quote appended at the front, and adding five of those quotes to the end (`(,5#{.)`). Then, it cyclically takes 30 characters from this 16-character string, which gives exactly Program 2 as a result.