# Program that outputs a program that outputs a program ... that outputs "Hello!"

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge

Write the shortest program P such that

- P takes any positive integer n as input, and outputs a program string P<sub>1</sub>
- executing P<sub>1</sub> (with no input) outputs a program string P<sub>2</sub>,
- executing P<sub>2</sub> (with no input) outputs a program string P<sub>3</sub>,
- ...
- executing P<sub>n</sub> (with no input) outputs exactly "Hello!" (without the quotes).

Schematically:

**P(n) → P<sub>1</sub> → P<sub>2</sub> → ... → P<sub>n</sub> → Hello!**

### Criteria

- I/O is via stdin/stdout.
- Program length is measured in bytes.
- Programs consist only of ASCII printable characters.
- There must be no duplicates among the programs P, P<sub>1</sub>,...,P<sub>n</sub>.

EDIT: Programs P, P<sub>1</sub>,...,P<sub>n</sub> are meant to be source code, and "executing the program" refers to whatever processing produces the output (i.e., interpretation, compilation & execution, etc.).

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5510/can-you-meta-quine

Comment: @dmckee - The relationship, if any, seems very remote. Schematically, a quine's behavior is like **P-->P**, and the linked programs' behavior is like **P-->Q-->P**; but here the behavior is like **P(n)-->...-->Hello!**, where **P** is not required to resemble *any* of the outputs.

Comment: That's not a criticism, r.e.s., just a note that people who like this problem might like the other one as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Golfscript <s>39</s> 14

```cs
~'Hello!'{`}@*
```

**Example:**

Assuming that **n=4** and our program is **P**, these are the steps:

1. [Run **P** with parameter **4**.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc0JwoKfidIZWxsbyEne2B9QCo%3D&run=true) The output is `"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"Hello!\\\\\\\"\\\"\""` (**P<sub>1</sub>**)
2. [Running **P<sub>1</sub>**](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IlwiXFxcIlxcXFxcXFwiSGVsbG8hXFxcXFxcXCJcXFwiXCIi&run=true) outputs `"\"\\\"Hello!\\\"\""` (**P<sub>2</sub>**)
3. [Running **P<sub>2</sub>**](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IlwiXFxcIkhlbGxvIVxcXCJcIiI%3D&run=true) outputs `"\"Hello!\""` (**P<sub>3</sub>**)
4. [Running **P<sub>3</sub>**](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IlwiSGVsbG8hXCIi&run=true) outputs `"Hello!"`(**P<sub>4</sub>**)
5. Running **P<sub>4</sub>** outputs `Hello!`. If you don't trust me, follow [this link](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IkhlbGxvISI%3D&run=true) ☺.

Comment: I find your P1,P2,P3,P4 behaving as required, but *with input from stdin* your P doesn't output P1 -- instead, it outputs `\'\\\'\\\\\\\'Hello!\\\\\\\'\\\'\'` (i.e., missing the outer quotes), when I run it both under Linux and under Win 7 (using `echo 4 | ...` at a command prompt). Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: @r.e.s. You are right; that's a shortcoming of the Golfscript testing website I made. I managed to fix that by adding three chars, but in the meantime I found a much shorter version and edited my post.

Comment: @r.e.s. The correct version of the old approach is `~''\(,{)2\?('\\'*}/]"'"*:z"'Hello!"z-1%"'"`

Comment: At 14 bytes, impressive! ... and nice website btw. (It seems that stdin can be simulated by preceding a program by `;"..."`, where `...` is the input. E.g., `;"4"` would have revealed the missing-quote problem above, whereas simply preceding the program by `"4"` does not.) ...

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right about the leading `;`. When I wrote the first program I forgot about this along the way, although it was me who wrote about it on the meta site: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/521/3527

Answer (score 4):

### Perl (<s>45</s> 36)

```
say"say q("x($m=<>),"Hello!",")"x$m
```

Run with `perl -M5.010` to use `say`.

For `n=1`, outputs `say q(Hello!)`
For `n=2`, outputs `say q(say q(Hello!))`
For `n=3`, outputs `say q(say q(say q(Hello!)))`
and so on.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, 58 chars

```
function $(_){alert(_?$+'$('+--_+')':'Hello!')}$(prompt())
```

Comment: How does it works?

Comment: @thepirat000 If the argument `_` is 0, it outputs "Hello!", otherwise it outputs the function definition and call with `_` minus one

Comment: +1 for abusing rules by using a counter rather than elongating the code...

Answer (score 2):

#### Python3, 66

```
r="print(%r)";e=eval;n=e(input())+1;e(e("(r%"*n+"'Hello!'"+")"*n))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Common Lisp, 68 characters

```
(do((n(read)(1- n))(s'(princ"Hello!")`(print',s)))((= 0 n)(eval s)))
```

```
(do ((n (read) (1- n))
     (s '(princ "Hello!") `(print ',s)))
    ((= 0 n) (eval s)))
```

The only non-straightforward thing: it generates one more level of program than needed and evaluates it, because `eval` is one character shorter than `print`.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp: 65

```
#1=(SETF N(READ)(CADDR'#1#)(1- N)W(PRINT(IF(= N 0)"Hello!"'#1#)))
```

This version is smaller than the existing CL-answer. In case your Lisp croaks with a stackoverflow, then you have to use this, 81 bytes:

```
#1=(SETF N(READ)*PRINT-CIRCLE* T(CADDR'#1#)(1- N)W(PRINT(IF(= N 0)"Hello!"'#1#)))
```

I know I'm late to the party, and I'm sure this could still be optimized.

Demonstration (careful, some online REPLs don't work correctly):

```
* #1=(SETF N(READ)*PRINT-CIRCLE* T(CADDR'#1#)(1- N)W(PRINT(IF(= N 0)"Hello!"'#1#)))
2
#1=(SETF N 1
         *PRINT-CIRCLE* T
         (CADDR '#1#) (1- N)
         W
           (PRINT
            (IF (= N 0)
                "Hello!"
                '#1#))) 
#1=(SETF N 1
         *PRINT-CIRCLE* T
         (CADDR '#1#) (1- N)
         W
           (PRINT
            (IF (= N 0)
                "Hello!"
                '#1#)))
* (eval *)

#1=(SETF N 0
         *PRINT-CIRCLE* T
         (CADDR '#1#) (1- N)
         W
           (PRINT
            (IF (= N 0)
                "Hello!"
                '#1#))) 
#1=(SETF N 0
         *PRINT-CIRCLE* T
         (CADDR '#1#) (1- N)
         W
           (PRINT
            (IF (= N 0)
                "Hello!"
                '#1#)))
* (eval *)
"Hello!" 
"Hello!"
*
```

Note that:

- Tested using SBCL 1.2.11.debian
- There are lots of warnings because I'm doing things that are seriously not supposed to be done. Thankfully, all warnings are printed with a semi-colon, so they would be treated as comments anyway.
- Duplication is because one is the return value and one actual output. If the return value would also count, then it simplifies to 58 bytes: `#1=(SETF N(READ)(CADDR'#1#)(1- N)W(IF(= N 0)"Hello!"'#1#))`
- I still know I'm late to the party

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 2.7, 57

```
print reduce(lambda x,y:y+`x`,input()*["print"],"Hello!")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 62

```
main=interact$(iterate(("main=putStr"++).show)"Hello!"!!).read
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash, 47 or 12 (if I use golfbash)

Code:

```
read x;for((;x>=0;x--)){ O+=" echo";};$O Hello!
```

golfbash code:

```
R;n e Hello!
```

Previous code (49):

```
read x;E=echo;eval \"\${E[0]\"{0..$x}\"}\" Hello!
```

Use:

Make program P

```
$ echo '<paste code here>' > P

$ chmod +x P
```

Example

Make P1:

```
$> echo 4 | ./P > 
echo echo echo echo Hello!
```

Make P2:

```
$> echo 4 | ./P | bash
echo echo echo Hello!
```

Make P3:

```
$ echo 4 | ./P | bash | bash
echo echo Hello!
```

Make P4:

```
$ echo 4 | ./P | bash | bash | bash
echo Hello!
```

Run P4:

```
$ echo 4 |./P | bash | bash | bash | bash
Hello!
```

Say that I make a new general purpose language called golfbash - at bit like golfscript - that has some useful commands like these:

```
R which reads stdin and places result into variable $REPLY.
n $1 $2 which echo's $1 $REPLY times followed by $2.
e which echo's all parameters to stdout.
```

Then I could write this:

```
R;n e Hello!
```

This would be legal, would't it?

Comment: That's rude. -1 for what?

Comment: +1. I guess the downvote was for your invented language that appears to be specifically for this challenge. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/871/creating-new-language-would-it-be-legal

Comment: Fine, but I did it in bash as well.

Answer (score 0):

**F#, 182**

```
let say msg = sprintf "%s" msg
let gen num = 
    let rec g n a =
        match n with
        | i when i > 0 -> g (i-1) ("say \"" + a + "\"")
        | _ -> say a
    g num "Hello!"
```

Comment: When I [run your program](http://ideone.com/kMfCr), it does not appear to input anything from stdin, nor to output anything to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## J - 31 char

Keep in mind that J uses Pascal-style strings: `'It''s too easy!'`

```
'Hello!'(],,)''''#~<:2^".1!:1]1
```

Explained:

- `".1!:1]1` - Read in a line from stdin and convert it to a number.
- `<:2^` - Take 2 to the power of this number, and decrement.
- `''''#~` - Make a string with that many copies of the single quote character.
- `'Hello!'(],,)` - Append these quotes to the front and back of `Hello!`.

Usage:

```
   'Hello!'(],,)''''#~<:2^".1!:1]1   NB. let's try 3
3
'''''''Hello!'''''''
   '''''''Hello!'''''''  NB. P1
'''Hello!'''
   '''Hello!'''          NB. P2
'Hello!'
   'Hello!'              NB. and P3 prints Hello!
Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7: 75

```
def h(n):
 return "Hello"if n<1 else'print %s' % `h(n-1)`
print h(input())
```

First time golfing, not sure if I'm doing it right ;p

Comment: Doesn't that assume that the definition of `h` is also known in the subsequent programs? (So that this would have to be run in a REPL or something?)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 36 bytes

```
(str(apply str(repeat 5\'))"Hello!")
```

Symbol

```
'something
```

evaluates to

```
something
```

Build up a symbol with 5 single quotes and run the result until no quotes left.