# Rube Goldberg Hello World

Tags: code-challenge, hello-world, code-generation

For this golf, you will need to use more than one language.

## The task

A [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) is a contraption that takes an enormous number of complicated steps in order to execute a very simple task. The goal of this golf is to output `Rube Goldberg`... but not directly.

## The machine

Your "machine" is the source code that, once executed, will give another source code in another language that will output `Rube Goldberg` upon execution. Got it?

I rephrase: your initial code must give another code, that other code must output `Rube Goldberg`. Both codes must be written in different languages.

## The bonus which is more like the only fun way to do it

There is a bonus if your code outputs a code that will output a code that will ... that will output `Rube Goldberg`.

*NOTE:* any sort of output can be used (stdout, stderr, dialog box, ...)

## The points

The number of points is equal to the number of bytes used in your code, divided by the number of **distinct**, **extra** languages that you used.

*NOTE:* different languages use different encodings. The number of bytes is counted in the initial language with its own encoding.

#### Examples

- `Pyth -> J -> Javascript -> output` in 30 bytes = 30/2 = **15 points** (J and Javascript are the extra languages)
- `Java -> C# -> C++ -> PHP -> output` in 36 bytes = 36/3 = **12 points** (More bytes and more languages can win over fewer bytes and fewer languages (I know there is no way that these languages do it in 36 bytes))
- `C -> output` in 10 bytes = 10/0 = **Infinity points** (No extra languages)
- `Python -> Perl -> Ruby -> Python -> Ruby` in 44 bytes = 44/2 = **22 points** (Perl and Ruby are the extra languages, the second Python is not counted as it is not an extra language, the second Ruby is not counted as it has already been used)

*NOTE:* Languages that output their input can't be used. That would be an extra language with absolutely no additional bytes.

## The answer

Please provide an answer that clearly states which languages you used and shows us the code at each step (i.e.: in each language).

## The winner

Of course, like usual, the lowest score wins.

*NOTE:* As usual, standard loopholes and "cheats" are not allowed.

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37357/31625)

Comment: code golf rube goldburg... It would have been better a popcorn but those always get shut down.

Comment: How to define byte count when different languages may use different encodings? The same char may count for example as 1 or 2 bytes depending on the language's encoding

Comment: @LuisMendo I figured you'd count the source code passed to the first language. If your languages use different encodings the main difficulty will be to output the correct encoding for the next language, won't it?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, I think counting for the first language makes sense. As for the other thing, I think it suffices to assume that the subsequent languages get _characters_ (regardless of their encoding)

Comment: [Another similar question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6544/31625), which requires input and is only for one language.

Comment: How closely related may the languages be? May I use Dyalog APL, NARS2000, ngn/apl, APL2, and APL+Win together? How about K, K2, K3,..., Kona?

Comment: Quine iterations (the program prints its source code) shouldn't be allowed. That would be a cheat.

Comment: Regarding characters: yes, you count the number of bytes in the initial source code for the initial language.

Comment: As there's some discussion on one of the answers, could you clarify whether "Languages that outputs their input can't be used." means "Programs which simply output their source code can't be used."? (I was assuming you were referring to things like PHP or /// which will print most characters in the source directly to STDOUT unless you include certain special characters, but it might be good to clarify that part.)

Comment: Surely there are languages that output their source + one byte, so that you could write your code by repeatedly using that language?

Comment: @BlackCap only different languages count.

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, but you don't get negative points for using it twice, so you could have a language read it's own code and add a `+` or something to a comment. If you find two languages that adds a different character you could write your program by repeatedly using those two languages with no score penalty. http://pastebin.com/dXQd89YQ

Comment: I don't think using the same language more than once should be allowed. If program A prints program B in many languages, and program B prints program A in even one language, I can alternate A and B over and over again, incrementing the language count without affecting the byte count.

Comment: "another code," "codes" http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20455/97308

Comment: To be clear, using the same language is allowed but won't help you as it is only counted once… So you add extra bytes when you use the language again, but can't increase the denominator.

Comment: One of the answers is counting Python 1, 2 and 3 as three separate languages. Is that allowed? (I don't think it should be.)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it should be either, Python is Python.

Comment: Is using language "Rube Goldberg" a cheat?

Comment: I don't know that language, but the answer is yes iff it has been created after Jun 22 '16 at 14:17. (No languages created after the challenge has been submited)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## 33 languages, 40 bytes, 1.25 points

`````
33.Bubblegum    : (hexdump) 3f1dbbbc87ebd1594f79fdbfa01c8a8ded64e1796d24d2f23e0115677f3cd9b3cd59c217c75a5c30
32.///          : "echo "B*"Rube Goldberg"+````{`]"print(%s)"e%}E*/
31.CJam         : "echo "B*"Rube Goldberg"+````{`]"print(%s)"e%}E*
30.Python       : (524,452 bytes)
29.Falcon       : (262,301 bytes)
28.Groovy       : (131,222 bytes)
27.JavaScript   : ( 65,679 bytes)
26.Julia        : ( 32,904 bytes)
25.Lua          : ( 16,513 bytes)
24.Move         : print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
23.Perl         : print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
22.Ruby         : print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
21.Sage         : print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
20.Swift        : print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
19.Yabasic      : print("print(\"print(\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\")\")")
18.MoonScript   : print("print(\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\")")
17.R            : print("\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"")
16.Arcyóu       : [1] "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
15.Convex       : "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
14.GolfScript   : "\"\\\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\\\"\""
13.Pyth         : "\"echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg\""
12.Foo          : "echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg"
11.ash          : echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
10.bash         : echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
09.csh          : echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
08.dash         : echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
07.fish         : echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
06.ksh          : echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
05.mksh         : echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
04.pash         : echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
03.rc           : echo echo echo Rube Goldberg
02.tcsh         : echo echo Rube Goldberg
01.zsh          : echo Rube Goldberg
00.OUTPUT       : Rube Goldberg
`````

Takes advantage of the fact that many different languages share the same printing syntax, resulting in exponentially longer but highly compressible source code.

#### Permalinks (incomplete, to be updated)

- [Bubblegum](http://bubblegum.tryitonline.net/#code=MDAwMDAwMDogM2YgMWQgYmIgYmMgODcgZWIgZDEgNTkgNGYgNzkgZmQgYmYgYTAgMWMgOGEgOGQgID8uLi4uLi5ZT3kuLi4uLi4KMDAwMDAxMDogZWQgNjQgZTEgNzkgNmQgMjQgZDIgZjIgM2UgMDEgMTUgNjcgN2YgM2MgZDkgYjMgIC5kLnltJC4uPi4uZy48Li4KMDAwMDAyMDogY2QgNTkgYzIgMTcgYzcgNWEgNWMgMzAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC5ZLi4uWlww&input=)
- [///](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=ImVjaG8gIkIqIlJ1YmUgR29sZGJlcmciK2BgYGB7YF0icHJpbnQoJXMpImUlfUUqLw&input=)
- [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22echo%20%22B*%22Rube%20Goldberg%22%2B%60%60%60%60%7B%60%5D%22print(%25s)%22e%25%7DE*)

Comment: If we are in fact allowed to use the same language more than once, I can achieve a much lower byte count without losing any languages, by repeatedly undoing what the previous program did.

Comment: You use 9-11 Unix Shells...

Comment: It is allowed to use languages more than once, but the second time you use it, it doesn't count as an additonnal language.

Comment: @SteeveDroz OK, my premise that it would improve the byte count seems to be off, but here's what I had in mind: The GolfScript program ``{"Rube Goldberg";'print('@@`'_~'+`')'}.~`` prints ``print("{\"Rube Goldberg\";'print('@@`'_~'+`')'}_~")``, which in turn prints the GolfScript program in Falcon, Groovy, JavaScript, Julia, etc. That means I can use GolfScript -> Falcon -> GolfScript -> Groovy... without ever changing the programs.

Comment: I love the rules abuse in this one... XD

Comment: You could use `BATCH`--another free `echo`.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That would require a `@` before `echo` (or `@echo off`) to eliminate the extra output, unless one of the other shells works in spite of it.

Comment: True. Why not after foo?

Comment: Because it would cause the next program (ash) to print an error message. The question seems to consider STDERR output, so I don't think it's allowed.

Comment: @Dennis I don't see the problem at first sight, can you explain where the flaw is?

Comment: @SteeveDroz I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean with Batch or with the GolfScript snippet?

Comment: Nevermind, I read it wrong… The answer is yes, you can use GolfScript every other step, but it only counts once. Let's be clear: GolfScript produces Falcon, then Falcon produces GolfScript, then GolfScript produces Groovy, etc.

Comment: @SteeveDroz Yes, that's the general idea. The GolfScript program I posted would print `Rube Goldberg` in Foo, so I could eventually each the desired output.

Comment: Gnuplot works for `print`. GDB batch mode works for `echo`. And yash.

Comment: @jimmy23013 I somehow missed your comment earlier. I'll add those soon. Thanks!

Comment: What did you do from CJam to Python? It seems you generate a lot more code there.

Comment: @justhalf Lots and lots of calls to `repr` (backtick in CJam).

Answer (score 55):

## [Foo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo) → [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2) → [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m/) → [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/) → [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina) → [Aeolbonn](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aeolbonn) → [Par](https://ypnypn.github.io/Par/) → [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously) → [Sprects](http://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html) → [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) → [Universal Lambda](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Universal_Lambda) → [Lines](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lines) → [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////) → [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html): 19/13 ≈ 1.4615 points

```
"“GḋÞḊCøẉYỴ⁴ñ<ȯƥ»Ṿ¦
```

All answers are given in the [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page). ¶ represents a newline.

## Mechanism

```
  Language      Code
 ——————————————————————————————————————
  Foo           "“GḋÞḊCøẉYỴ⁴ñ<ȯƥ»Ṿ¦
  gs2           “GḋÞḊCøẉYỴ⁴ñ<ȯƥ»Ṿ¦
  M             “GḋÞḊCøẉYỴ⁴ñ<ȯƥ»Ṿ
  Jelly         “¶:`".c Rube Goldberg#\/”
  Retina        ¶:`".c Rube Goldberg#\/
  Aeolbonn      :`".c Rube Goldberg#\/
  Par           `".c Rube Goldberg#\/
  Actually      ".c Rube Goldberg#\/
  Sprects       .c Rube Goldberg#\/
  sed           c Rube Goldberg#\/
  U.Lambda       Rube Goldberg#\/
  Lines         Rube Goldberg#\/
  ///           Rube Goldberg#/
  m4            Rube Goldberg#
```

EDIT: Oops, there was an error in the Pyth program. I replaced Pyth and GolfScript by Par.

EDIT 2: Added GNU m4.

EDIT 3: Added Foo and M.

Comment: lol how `gs2 -> Jelly` only removes one byte...

Comment: If you write a brainfuck programm that generates that gs2 programm, you could convert that brainfuck programm to [unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) and add one more language before that and add two languages and likely cut off some bytes off the initial code.

Comment: @overactor: The initial code would definitely be longer. Sure, it’s “just” printing a bunch of zeros, but the exact number of zeros to print is astronomical

Comment: Well, no sense in trying now :P (except for the fun of it)

Comment: I wrote all answers in the Jelly code page. gs2 and Foo just use byte I/O, so the “encoding” I use to represent high-ASCII bytes _in this answer_ doesn’t really matter, I believe.

Comment: @overactor No, do it in [Golunar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar)!

Comment: Since you have both /// and Lines, I guess you could also consider adding https://esolangs.org/wiki/Itflabtijtslwi (just add another `/` to the end, if that doesn't mess up any other languages).

Comment: Where does the string Rube Goldberg come from? This is confusing.

Comment: @lightswitchr It uses M's built-in string compression which decodes that jumble of characters to give the Jelly code.

Comment: You could add V to this fairly easy. To denote a string literal in V, just prepend any of these characters to what you want to print: `iIaARC` I don't know these other languages very well, so I can't guarantee it would improve your score.

Answer (score 32):

## Jolf -> Actually -> Jelly -> Pyth -> Retina -> /// -> Golfscript: 15 / 6 = 2.5 points

5.4 points thanks to Martin Ender.

0.1 points thanks to Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ.

Note: both Actually and Jelly have their own code-page, so they could be transfered byte-by-byte, just not in the Online versions.

#### Jolf

```
aq"“'ẉ'ɠ@ịQCṁỊ»
```

#### Actually

```
"“'ẉ'ɠ@ịQCṁỊ»
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=IuKAnCfhuoknyaBA4buLUUPhuYHhu4rCuw&input=)

#### Jelly

```
“'ẉ'ɠ@ịQCṁỊ»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcJ-G6iSfJoEDhu4tRQ-G5geG7isK7&input=)

#### Pyth

```
k"'Rube Goldberg'/
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=k%22%27Rube+Goldberg%27%2F&debug=0)

#### Retina

```
'Rube Goldberg'/
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CidSdWJlIEdvbGRiZXJnJy8&input=)

#### ///

```
'Rube Goldberg'/
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=J1J1YmUgR29sZGJlcmcnLw&input=)

#### Golfscript

```
'Rube Goldberg'
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=J1J1YmUgR29sZGJlcmcn&input=)

Answer (score 26):

## Python -> Batch -> Javascript -> Java -> PHP -> C++ -> Foo -> Brainfuck 31.(142857) points

### Python

```
print'@echo alert`void f(){System.out.println("echo\"void f(){cout<<\\"\\\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\\\"\\"}\""`'
```

### Batch

```
@echo alert`void f(){System.out.println("echo\"void f(){cout<<\\"\\\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\\\"\\"}\""`
```

### JavaScript

```
alert`void f(){System.out.println("echo\"void f(){cout<<\\"\\\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\\\"\\"}\""`
```

### Java

```
void f(){System.out.println("echo\"void f(){cout<<\\"\\\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\\\"\\"}\""
```

### PHP

```
echo"void f(){cout<<\"\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\"\"}"
```

### C++

```
void f(){cout<<"\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\""}
```

### Foo

```
"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------."
```

### BrainFuck

```
-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.
```

Comment: Did you just include BF to make the byte-count long?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, I already made a short version, now this goes for the most langauges as possible

Comment: I don't know which to prefer, BF or Java.

Comment: Couldn't you make the python one a little bit shorter by using string repetition? For example, instead of `-----------` couldn't you do `"+"-"*11+"`?

Answer (score 21):

### JS -> Cobol -> Python -> IBM 360 BAL

261 bytes/4 languages = 65.25 Points

*Was aiming to use difficult languages, with more obfuscation. Javascript converts the string from base64 into Cobol, which produces Python that decodes the BAL code from hex.*

**Javascript**

```
console.log(atob(' 1
    LH8T88d@05R850T8LT88!Q!R Cek*k{[~&vgm88yx9m4m6y6m8wx9m6}s}6Ovm9m6kg7m4m6x{m69x{6Ovm8wOxxg8Ovm9yOym4m6sv9x{6Ovm8km69Oxs}w}snxv86m69Ox7}m69x{49xyx}wws88wsg88oww}g4Ovkm4Oxyxww}}7g8{9swyyg9wyym6Ovm8Oxwxm6fm6gyxm8sox6m6gyxm6gkm6gLP');
```

**Cobol**

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. Rube.
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 DATA DIVISION.
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    Display ' print bytearray.fromhex("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").decode()'.
    STOP RUN.
```

**Python**

```
 print bytearray.fromhex("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").decode()
```

**IBM 360 BAL**

```
 // EXEC ASSEMBLY
      START
 MAIN   BALR  2,0
      USING *,2
      OPEN  PRINT
      MVC   BUF,HW
      PUT   PRINT
      CLOSE PRINT
      EOJ
 HW DC  CL132'RUBE GOLDBERG'
 BUF    DS  CL132
 PRINT  DTFPR IOAREA1=BUF,DEVADDR=SYSLST,BLKSIZE=132,       *
        DEVICE=3203,CONTROL=YES,PRINTOV=YES 
      END   MAIN
 /*
 // EXEC LNKEDT
 // EXEC
 /*
 /&
```

**Output**

```
RUBE GOLDBERG
```

Comment: +1 Most other answers just use different printing functions one after another, but you combined it with base64 and hex encoding. Great first answer, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Wrong Case. The output should be `Rude Goldberg`, not `RUBE GOLDBERG`.

Comment: Actually, the Python solution will throw `IndentationError` and not run.

Comment: Every COBOL program I see looks like commands for a alien spaceship...

Comment: enjoy the association bonus :D

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Is that something like Congrats on 200 rep?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer in a way yes. I just noticed because I upvoted when he was at 191

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala It seems the user hasn't done anything since then, since he has 301 rep (201 + 100).

Answer (score 17):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) -> [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/) -> [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) -> [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) <s>21/2</s> <s>18/2</s> 22/3

*Thanks for Martin for 3 chars off!*

```
'"''Rube Goldberg''"`'
```

executed [in MATL](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JyInJ1J1YmUgR29sZGJlcmcnJyJgJw&input=) gives

```
"''Rube Goldberg''"`
```

which [in CJam](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IidSdWJlIEdvbGRiZXJnJyJg&input=) gives

```
"'Rube Goldberg'"
```

which [in 05AB1E](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IidSdWJlIEdvbGRiZXJnJyI&input=) gives

```
'Rube Goldberg'
```

which [in Golfscript](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=J1J1YmUgR29sZGJlcmcn&input=) gives

```
Rube Goldberg
```

Comment: [You can add Pyth in 1 byte](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%22+u%01%0A%C3%A1%C2%B6%7D%C2%B5%7Cy%C3%81%C3%8B1%C2%A9%C3%B2i%C3%B7&debug=0), I think.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks! But I have no idea of Pyth or how that code works, so I wont' add it. Maybe use it yourself? :-)

Comment: Golfscript -> Pyth. Then, your original source code will convert `g'` to `g`. So your score will be **7** instead of **22/3**.

Comment: But it would then be 21/4, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

## Reng -> ><> -> Vitsy, 32 / 2 = 16 points

I wanted to do *only* 2D languages--on a single line!

```
{'Z"Rube Goldberg"'ol?!;f3+0.}n~
```

### Explanation

```
Reng sees:  {'Z"Rube Goldberg"'ol?!;f3+0.}n~
            <---------------------------->    code block
                                          n~  print that and stop

><> sees:   {'Z"Rube Goldberg"'ol?!;f3+0.}
            {                                 no-op?
             'Z"Rube Goldberg"'               push that string backwards
                               o              output a char
                                l?!;          terminate if none are left
                                    f3+0.     go to (0, 18) in the codebox

Vitsy sees: "grebdloG ebuR"Z
            "............."                   push that string
                           Z                  output it
```

Comment: **32 / 2 = 16**, not 32. Also, can't you do push the string written backwards instead of wrapping it (><>)?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Vitsy requires a string backwards, so in essence the string is backwards from ><> to Vitsy. And thanks for the clarification for the score.

Comment: I was confused with "`push that string backwards`".

Comment: My child appreciates your usage. +1

Comment: It is worth noting that Vitsy is 1D syntax, but its data handling is 4D.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Technically 2D with `m`ethod (love that instruction). And 4D is close enough :P

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ But that jumps to separate lines - count that as 2D, and Java is a 2D language.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE .... ehhhh okay

Answer (score 4):

### Perl -> JavaScript (ES6) -> Batch -> sh, 39 / 3 = 13 points

### Perl

```
print 'alert`@echo echo Rube Goldberg`'
```

### JavaScript (ES6)

```
alert`@echo echo Rube Goldberg`
```

### Batch

```
@echo echo Rube Goldberg
```

### sh

```
echo Rube Goldberg
```

Comment: You can add PHP into it: ``<?="print 'alert`@echo echo Rube Goldberg`'";``. If I'm not wrong, it will be 11.25 points.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Don't know PHP, but I think that `print 'alert\`@echo echo Rube Goldberg\`'` works in PHP as well.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ You're right. I had this idea that PHP required parenthesys to run the `print`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I mean, you can omit the `<?php` part to act as a quine I think.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I don't think that that is allowed. It would be just a simple plain-text file being fed into PHP.

Answer (score 4):

## Java->Thue->Javascript->Batch->Microscript II->Brainf***, 236/5=47.2

```
interface J{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("a::=~alert`echo \"+++++[>+A<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++AA.+++.>>++++[>+A<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>A.>+AA.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++.\"`\n::=\na".replaceAll("A","+++++++"));}}
```

---

Generated Thue program:

```
a::=~alert`echo "+++++[>++++++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++++++++++++++++.+++.>>++++[>++++++++<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++++++++.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++."`
::=
a
```

Generated Javascript program:

```
alert`echo "+++++[>++++++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++++++++++++++++.+++.>>++++[>++++++++<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++++++++.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++."`
```

Generated Batch program:

```
echo "+++++[>++++++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++++++++++++++++.+++.>>++++[>++++++++<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++++++++.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++."
```

Generated Microscript II program:

```
"+++++[>++++++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++++++++++++++++.+++.>>++++[>++++++++<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++++++++.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++."
```

Generated Brainf*** program:

```
+++++[>++++++++<-]>[>++>+++<<-]>++.>---.<++++++++++++++++.+++.>>++++[>++++++++<-]>.[>++>+++>+++<<<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++++++++.---.>++++.--.+++.<<<<<---.>>>>>++.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage) → [4DOS](https://www.4dos.info) → [4OS2](https://www.4dos.info/v4os2.htm) → [Almquist shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/ash) → [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) → [Bourne Again shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash) → [COMMAND.COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) → [C shell](http://bxr.su/NetBSD/bin/csh) → [Debian Almquist shell](http://gondor.apana.org.au/%7Eherbert/dash) → [Desktop Korn shell](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1365/6jalh9ls5/index.html) → [Extensible shell](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell) → [Friendly Interactive shell](http://fishshell.com) → [Hamilton C shell](https://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) → [Ion shell](https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/ion) → [Inferno shell](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/papers/sh.html) → [KornShell](http://www.kornshell.org) → [MirBSD Korn shell](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) → [MKS Korn shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/bb463204(v=technet.10)) → [NDOS](https://us.norton.com/products) → [OpenBSD Korn shell](https://github.com/ibara/oksh) → [OS/2 Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe#OS/2) → [Pocket CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe#Windows_CE) → [Public Domain Korn shell](http://web.cs.mun.ca/%7Emichael/pdksh) → [ReactOS Command Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe#ReactOS) → [Run Commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc) → [Steve Koren shell](http://aminet.net/package/util/shell/SKsh21) → [Thompson shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) → [Take Command Console](https://jpsoft.com/products/tcc-cmd-prompt.html) → [Tool Command Language KornShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20090316024446/http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ejlk/tksh) → [Tool Command Language shell](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/UserCmd/tclsh.htm) → [TENEX C shell](https://www.tcsh.org) → [Windows Command Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe#Windows_NT_family) → [Z shell](https://zsh.sourceforge.io), \$\frac{15}{32}=0.46875\$

Beats all other answers. All it took was a couple centuries of looking for shells with `echo`.

1. **Jelly:** `“¡oġ»ẋ32“,oƝ+Ƈ»`
2. **4DOS:**  `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
3. **4OS2:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
4. **Almquist shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
5. **Bourne shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
6. **Bourne Again shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
7. **COMMAND.COM:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
8. **C shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
9. **Debian Almquist shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
10. **Desktop Korn shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
11. **Extensible shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
12. **Friendly Interactive shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
13. **Hamilton C shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
14. **Inferno shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
15. **Ion shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
16. **KornShell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
17. **MirBSD Korn shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
18. **MKS Korn shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
19. **NDOS:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
20. **OpenBSD Korn shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
21. **OS/2:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
22. **Pocket CMD:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
23. **Public Domain Korn shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
24. **ReactOS Command Prompt:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
25. **Run Commands:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
26. **Steve Koren shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
27. **Thompson shell:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
28. **Take Command Console:** `echo echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
29. **Tool Command Language KornShell:** `echo echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
30. **Tool Command Language shell:** `echo echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
31. **TENEX C shell:** `echo echo echo Rube Goldberg`
32. **Windows Command Prompt:** `echo echo Rube Goldberg`
33. **Z shell:** `echo Rube Goldberg`
34. **Output:** `Rube Goldberg`

Comment: Go add Powershell to it!!!

Comment: @Wasif I would, but sadly when `echo` is given space-delimited arguments (like `echo Hello, World!`) not surrounded in quotes, it outputs each argument on a separate line.

Comment: Hmm... Sorry looks like Powershell interprets that as an array

Comment: @Wasif Yeah. Either way, doesn't matter, all that matters is Powershell won't work here.

Comment: Just had to delete Pash because it gives that same behavior :/

Comment: this is awful. I love it

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript -> PHP -> Foo 14 points

Javascript:

```
alert`echo'"Rube Goldberg"'`
```

PHP:

```
echo'"Rube Goldberg"'
```

Foo:

```
"Rube Goldberg"
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL → J → K, 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9411/43319)/2 → 10.5

`'''"Rube Goldberg"'''`
on Dyalog APL gives
`'"Rube Goldberg"'`
which in J gives
`"Rube Goldberg"`
which in K gives
`Rube Goldberg`

If we allow even closer related languages we can get many more.

Answer (score 3):

### /// -> PowerShell -> CJam -> Foo -> BASH, 24 bytes/4 = 6

```
'"echo Rube Goldberg"p'/
```

When executed in /// gives

```
'"echo Rube Goldberg"p'
```

which, when executed in PowerShell gives

```
"echo Rube Goldberg"p
```

which, when executed in CJam gives

```
"echo Rube Goldberg"
```

which, when executed in Foo gives

```
echo Rube Goldberg
```

which, when executed in BASH gives

```
Rube Goldberg
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python → Ruby → Bash, score: 35 / 2 = 17.5

```
print"puts'echo \"Rube Goldberg\"'"
```

when executed in Python, gives

```
puts'echo "Rube Goldberg"'
```

with the `\"`s escaped. Next, this, executed Ruby gives

```
echo "Rube Goldberg"
```

and lastly, executing this in Bash gives

```
Rube Goldberg
```

which is the expected string.

Answer (score 1):

## C → JS → Shell → [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish): 68 / 3 = 22.67

#### C

```
main(){puts("console.log(`echo '\"Rube Goldberg\"ar!;ooooooo|'`)");}
```

#### Javascript

```
console.log(`echo '"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|'`)
```

#### Shell

```
echo '"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|'
```

#### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```
"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|
```

Result:

```
Rube Goldberg
```

as required.

Comment: **72/3 = 24**, not 36

Comment: I think there are "template strings" in JS, thus you can do `console.log\`echo '"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|'\``?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Thanks, apparently can't count :p And also thanks for the template strings suggestion; forgot about that... Although the no-parens trick doesn't seem to work, because console.log then goes outputting an array (at least in Node)

Comment: It's not worth it to make such approximations; use 22.(6)7 instead, it's smaller by 0.(0)3.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Sorry, but that doesn't work. Tagged template strings evaluate differently (that would evaluate to roughly `console.log([\`echo '"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|'\`])`) as per spec.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows You mean `console.log(['echo \'"Rube Goldberg"ar!;ooooooo|\''])`

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ They're the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sprects](https://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html) → [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) → [itflabtijtslwi](https://esolangs.org/wiki/itflabtijtslwi) → Python 2 → Pyth, 24 / 4 = 6

## Sprects

```
$print'"Rube Goldberg'\/
```

## ///

```
print'"Rube Goldberg'\/
```

## itflabtijtslwi

```
print'"Rube Goldberg'/
```

## Python 2

```
print'"Rube Goldberg'
```

## Pyth

```
"Rube Goldberg
```

## Output

```
Rube Goldberg
```

Answer (score 1):

## /// -> K -> J -> SX -> Golfscript -> Pyke -> Lua -> Moonscript -> C -> Pyth -> Python -> BrainF*** -> Bash -> Ruby -> Zsh, 554b/16= 34.625

### ///

```
"'我（\"\\\"print \\\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\")\\\\\"\\\"\"）'"/
```

### K

```
"'我（\"\\\"print \\\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\")\\\\\"\\\"\"）'"
```

### J

```
'我（\"\\\"print \\\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\")\\\\\"\\\"\"）'
```

### SX

```
我（\"\\\"print \\\\\"print(\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\")\\\\\"\\\"\"）
```

### Golfscript

```
"\"print \\\"print(\\\\\"print \\\\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\"\\\\\")\\\"\""
```

### Pyke

```
"print \"print(\\\"print \\\\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\"\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\");}\\\\\"\\\")\""
```

### Perl

```
print "print(\"print \\\"#include<stdio.h>\\\nint main(){printf(\\\\\"\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\\\"\\\\\");}\\\"\")"
```

### Lua

```
print("print \"#include<stdio.h>\nint main(){printf(\\\"\\\\\"print \\\\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\\\"\\\");}\"")
```

### Moonscript

```
print "#include<stdio.h>\nint main(){printf(\"\\\"print \\\\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\"\");}"
```

### C

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){printf("\"print \\\"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\\\"");}
```

### Pyth

```
"print \"--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\"
```

### Python 2

```
print "--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>."
```

### BrainF***

```
--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.--[-->+++<]>.+[-->+++<]>.-[-->+<]>--.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-.-[->++++++<]>.[->+++<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.>-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.-----------.-[->++++++<]>.\
```

### Bash

```
echo -E puts \"echo Rube Goldberg\"
```

### Ruby

```
puts "echo Rube Goldberg"
```

### Zsh

```
echo Rube Goldberg
```

Obviously I could add a lot of echo's but it feels like it would copy Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 1):

## sed -> Pyth -> Python -> AWK -> Make -> Bash, 200/4 = 50

```
s/.*/=Z"echo"p"print(~BEGIN{print\\"r=S\\"Rube GoldbergS\\"Sntrue =;@Y"(){ Y" S\\"${r}S\\"|awk \\\\~$0=S\\"x:SSnSSt@Y" S\\"$0\\\\~;}Sntrue :SnSt@YdpZp" ${r}\\"}~)"p"/
s/S/\\\\\\\\/g;s/~/'/g;s/Y/"pZp/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7BCsIwFLv7FeUxcAr6dt4YDEGGFw/2tLGLc6WK0pV2Q2Guv17bMnN44SUhRLNux8Vorcb9FvMa2O3egwSpHmKIzeFYns5TeJoGVE7dvYwtI2X/6lqmuBeoGNTISJ4VFcSbiVRAvBxNavb8vb6fpHEwURIKPimlgtKh@AeT4GbzUpQ615mdrCUQ3@Iys9m4VbjSSLFZgDzTaHAduEJweeTW/gA)

Not the shortest, or the most languages, but I enjoyed figuring this out.  And the second to the last step in the chain is Make/Bash polyglot.  If you run it as a Makefile, it generates a Bash script.  If you run it as a Bash script, it generates a Makefile.

#### Pyth

```
=Z"echo"p"print('BEGIN{print\"r=\\\\\"Rube Goldberg\\\\\"\\\\ntrue =;@"pZp"(){ "pZp" \\\\\"${r}\\\\\"|awk \\'$0=\\\\\"x:\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\t@"pZp" \\\\\"$0\\';}\\\\ntrue :\\\\n\\\\t@"pZpdpZp" ${r}\"}')"p"
```

The `p"` at the end is only necessary since I can't find a way to make `sed` leave off the trailing LF and Pyth really hates blank input source lines...  At least the TIO version does.  I found adding a print statement follow by an open string squelched the error.

#### Python

```
print('BEGIN{print"r=\\"Rube Goldberg\\"\\ntrue =;@echo(){ echo \\"${r}\\"|awk \'$0=\\"x:\\\\n\\\\t@echo \\"$0\';}\\ntrue :\\n\\t@echo echo ${r}"}')
```

#### AWK

```
BEGIN{print"r=\"Rube Goldberg\"\ntrue =;@echo(){ echo \"${r}\"|awk '$0=\"x:\\n\\t@echo \"$0';}\ntrue :\n\t@echo echo ${r}"}
```

#### Make/Bash polyglot

```
r="Rube Goldberg"
true =;@echo(){ echo "${r}"|awk '$0="x:\n\t@echo "$0';}
true :
        @echo echo ${r}
```

Since that has to work as a Makefile, there are tabs in the original, which don't cut-n-paste into this page properly...

#### Bash (if you treat the Make/Bash step as Make)

```
echo Rube Goldberg
```

#### Make (if you treat the Make/Bash script as Bash)

```
x:
        @echo Rube Goldberg
```

And again, there's a tab in the original...

Answer (score 0):

### Python -> Ruby -> Bash -> JS -> /// -> m4, score: 54 / 5 = 10.8

```
Original  print"puts\"echo \'alert(\\\"Rube Goldberg#/\\\")'\""
Python    puts"echo 'alert(Rube Goldberg)'"
Ruby      echo 'alert("Rube Goldberg#/")'
Bash      alert("Rube Goldberg#/")
JS        Rube Goldberg#/
///       Rube Goldberg#
m4        Rube Goldberg
```

I've got the /// and m4 trick from the answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83627/53416

Answer (score 0):

### dc -> Fortran -> Basic -> Vim, 59/3 = 19.(6) points

With this answer I wanted to contribute to the variety of languages already used in other answers.

**dc:**

```
[program P;write(*,*)"PRINT ""echo 'Rube Goldberg'""";end]P
```

**Fortran:**

```fortran
program P;write(*,*)"PRINT ""echo 'Rube Goldberg'""";end
```

**Basic:**

```basic
PRINT "echo 'Rube Goldberg'"
```

**Vim:**

```vim
echo 'Rube Goldberg'
```

**Final output:**

```
Rube Goldberg
```

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript -> Python -> Bash -> Ruby -> ///, 49/4 = 12.25 points

**GolfScript:**
`"print('echo puts \\\\\\'Rube Goldberg/\\\\'')"`

**Python:**
`print('echo puts \\\'Rube Goldberg/\\\'')`

**Bash:**
`echo puts \'Rube Goldberg/\'`

**Ruby:**
`puts 'Rube Goldberg/'`

**///:**
`Rube Goldberg/`

**Output:**
Rube Goldberg