# Output a program that outputs a program ... that outputs PPCG

Tags: code-challenge, code-generation

### Challenge:

Write a code that, when executed will output the source code of a second program that can be executed in another language. The second program should output the source code of a third program that can be executed in a third language and so on. The last program should output **`PPCG`** with an optional single trailing newline.

The winner will be the submission with the most languages. Code length of the first program will be the tie breaker.

**Important rules:**

1. No programs can be identical
2. Each language must only work on one of the source codes. It should be impossible to use the same language two places in the chain without breaking it<sup>(see examples)</sup>.

   - A shortened chain is not a broken chain. If you can use a language in a different place than intended and the end result is still PPCG then it's invalid
3. All versions of a language count as unique languages (but keep in mind rule number 2)

---

### Examples:

**An invalid submission:**

```
print("""print'disp("PPCG")'""")
```

- Python 3: `print("""print'disp("PPCG")'""")` prints `print'disp("PPCG")'`
- Python 2: `print'disp("PPCG")'` prints `disp("PPCG")`
- Octave  : `disp("PPCG")` prints `PPCG`

This works properly, **but:** you can run both the first and the second code in Python 2 without breaking the chain, so this violates rule number 2.

**A valid submission with score 3:**

```
print("""print'disp("PPCG")'""")
```

- Python 3: `print("""print'disp("PPCG")'""")` prints `print'disp("PPCG")'`
- Perl    : `print'disp("PPCG")'` prints `disp("PPCG")`
- Octave  : `disp("PPCG")` prints `PPCG`

This is the exact same code as the invalid example. The difference is, we have chosen languages that adhere to rule number 2: You can't run the first code in Perl/Octave, the second code in Python 3/Octave nor the last code in Python 3/Perl. This is valid even though Python 2 can run the two first programs, because we haven't used Python 2 as one of the languages.

Comment: [Related, but not a duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6544/program-that-outputs-a-program-that-outputs-a-program-that-outputs-hello).

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83564/42545) Practically the same challenge, but the scoring system takes into account the length of the code.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't really noticed rule 2. That makes it definitely not a duplicate in my eyes.

Comment: Rule 2 makes Rule 1 redundant.

Comment: It's unfortunate this challenge has the no-repeats rule, which is novel, but ALSO has the "must end with PPCG" instead of it being otherwise a normal ouroboros challenge.

Comment: The final output of PPCG can optionally have a trailing newline. Can the intermediate stages have trailing newlines that "don't count"? E.g. if stage 2 outputs a trailing newline, must that newline be included in the stage 3 code?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. You don't need to include trailing newlines in the code in the intermediate stages.

Answer (score 16):

## 12 languages, 64 bytes

### [Charcoal](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@zwaNQo2Cosy8Eg11/Qp9MEu/QklJqUKh0MZeKSFTT0vJyt7ZI0hFw9hEU1spRj0gwNk9Rj1ByQ6oSF3L8P9/AA) -> [tinylisp](https://tio.run/nexus/tinylisp#@69RqFFQlJlXoqGuX6EPZulXKCkpVSgU2tgrJWTqaSlZ2Tt7BKloGJtoaivFqAcEOLvHqCco2QEVqWsZ/v8PAA) -> [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@69RUJSZV6Kgoa5foQ9m6lcoKSlVKBTa2CslZOppKVnZO3sEqShoGJtoKmgrxagHBDi7x6gnKNkBlalrGWpq/v8PAA) -> [///](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@69foV9QlJlXol@hpKRUoVBoY6@UkKmnpWRl7@wRpKKgYWyiqaCtpB4Q4OyunqBkB1T0/z8A) -> [Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXoqSkBKYVCm3slRIy9bSUrOydPYJUFDSMTTQVtJXUAwKc3dUTlOyACv//BwA) -> [Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@19QlJlXolBoY6@UkKmnpWRl7@wRpKKgYWyiqaCtpB4Q4OyunqBk9/8/AA) -> QBasic -> [Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@5@QqafFpaQeEODsrp7w/z8A) -> [V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5@pp8WlpB4Q4Oyu/v8/AA) -> [Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nxaWkHhDg7K7@/z8A) -> [Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@6@kHhDg7K7@/z8A) -> [GolfScript](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@68eEODsrv7/PwA)

#### Charcoal

```
Ｐ(q(print('/x/print/x"""x q<?"`i.*":?CHR$(34)+"\'PPCG\'`">"""'*1
```

Any run of printable ASCII is a string literal in Charcoal. `Ｐ` can be used for multidirectional printing, but in this case it simply prints the string going rightward.

#### tinylisp

```
(q(print('/x/print/x"""x q<?"`i.*":?CHR$(34)+"\'PPCG\'`">"""'*1
```

The only reserved characters in tinylisp (as of this writing) are parentheses and whitespace. Any other run of characters is a token, even something like `` +"\'PPCG\'`">"""'*1 ``. Parentheses define lists. The `q` (quote) builtin returns its argument unevaluated--in this case, the nested list `` (print ('/x/print/x"""x q<?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"\'PPCG\'`">"""'*1)) ``. (Missing parentheses at the end are autocompleted.)

#### Python 3

```
(print ('/x/print/x"""x q<?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"\'PPCG\'`">"""'*1))
```

Since `print` is a function in Python 3, we can wrap it in parentheses with no problem. In Python 2, where it's a statement, this is a syntax error. Unfortunately, Perl is fine with the parentheses, so we also do `*1` (string repetition in Python, cast to int and multiply in Perl).

#### ///

```
/x/print/x"""x q<?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"'PPCG'`">"""
```

`/x/print/` changes `x` to `print` in the rest of the program, which has no slashes and therefore is output with no further changes.

#### Python 2

```
print"""print q<?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"'PPCG'`">"""
```

No parentheses after `print`, doesn't work in Python 3. Perl doesn't like the triple quotes.

#### Perl

```
print q<?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"'PPCG'`">
```

Perl's various ways of quoting a string are helpful, and distinct from other languages. Here we use `q<...>`.

#### QBasic

```
?"`i.*":?CHR$ (34) +"'PPCG'`"
```

A couple of print statements (abbreviated as `?`), using `CHR$(34)` to get a double quote.

#### Pip

```
`i.*
"'PPCG'`
```

A single Pattern (regex) literal in backticks.

#### V

```
i.*
"'PPCG'
```

Switch to insert mode, add some text.

#### Retina

```
.*
"'PPCG'
```

Match anything and replace it with the second line.

#### Pyth

```
"'PPCG'
```

Pyth quotes don't need to be matched (which makes this not a valid program in Pip).

#### GolfScript

```
'PPCG'
```

Comment: Any documentation on charcoal?

Comment: @ev3commander Sort of. See [list of commands](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Commands), brief notes on [syntax](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Syntax) (mainly literals), and [code page](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page). But yeah, the documentation isn't great. I added some explanation to the answer, too.

Comment: ah. I was wondering because the P wasn't actually a pure ASCII p, but I guess it was so that it wouldn't print "Pprint...." not "print...."

Comment: Add bash: `echo '…'` to the beginning

Answer (score 13):

## <s>14</s> <s>16</s> <s>17</s> 18 Languages: [Fueue](https://github.com/TryItOnline/fueue) > 05AB1E > APL (dzaima/APL) > Charcoal > Javascript (Node.js) > Go > C# > Emojicode > Java > C++ > LOLCODE > brainfuck > ruby > C > Python > /// > Fish > Befunge, 2139 Bytes

> [Fueue program that's 30410 bytes long](https://tio.run/##7V0LctwgDL3KHiEYYTs36EXSG@T8W@NNWxAg//gIr2Y6mWITDE/Sk1D4/P7@@v56Ps30gM8HzI/lP4NWDzM@jLYF87GW1bQ8U3/friVYayhbY6n97/HkVrJtrv/Qgxk9WFoif2V2P/F64NQwg@0NWT/WonIbcLqExqnCAbmgLOM1xOhn/NqkuxEOTLmf8gSUbE6nsX5JlKw/k4NNiHOBDz2AxBCMwpVncoTR5gZ6QLi7CCIfkQmLOifcAy4RkrVWpC4h4xnBov6hkQ0HOh9rH9nIsAV0qFsbH/SN0tecEeGzvAsVUaf7HxhXKF@NpT2lSSVUhtjndXo0W@KhGSv4lahyTrSG0YBFRwhpiW7Z0uceTsYag1TOQdBsEutu09ynPCcMyNfnySOAidD1GPLDpjLoc1xjHblp6rGtbZvDWFO2jchqwugSHsmCY37E42pYDESzGjIG4xUQLc9QpBBrYVx/ThFbIdyYrT9uob3TMsvS3DUj3faR9XDqnS9zRzNjRBQ34cuQISvEHkMIX/gJszf8S9lGzgiQItWzJT@6V8ciyA0qi2I4hyqY9JwLFKG@6k2hHQ8rkNoTYZ313R9lRUKUUjZ8SKnqzblOxMAhqWrPO@rDqQ/Shgl1QyXVUu4VTN8gJFyyNoQnGNKkagOyOY01ikeHRHRq21T3Qv6IhVswICUKz02id4B/D7x30/uodh4jJ3KUN8Rs/9iFQlNEhabf@noJMPWqfSXAUZs62SacHANcx4Xq56HxZe9nA6kk5VAC3Qu9PtXPQn3RRM/guhVn00/Vu0ae/XqVUnbLKcHl2ZihBJeXKEFxSauaX2ju42pLGq4zWBXOgpqMwqwEbFmYaV@aa@tZBHdqJLNIPEOva0exrGPaUxbXrc53ESWUQLcK8n3GPeoG9sB3/qfbaXmJfI/MZfLOhDnZdO1cbInoQmYTPGws0CWCpQ4wkS4wo@Wb4dGdeAtOuQsteT5ueb6OZlKntIC1zkuOrNXXoZ236CiDdb9M6f4ZA6eYqEOPx9p3SKwhf1OkJQ39/T2HWS4WuKwjYx2tlbf@XuIQiTw4Zif5IthhdrkQZ5VACWrOgQ61Aoz0RbhVuPW9ufV@K8caMh@z1Te67E4JZqtFoOyaheY5OfFV4qvEV4mvapFlhJpM23bVFbO5oWSbxMuIl5Fs01tnm26yZws6WfGS3ff3suKa9WxXX5dRlVKHe5Oa77DPvlu8bbbpljFKn9qjbrDOX8vaCoa5Snir3R6yLlbWxcq6WFkX2/jcH747HvieidBLNMP6VDpd3ANB73v8au/4u8nZRV2csFYlF1v4XDi@J1yUkHtHJwCqmvrZfH9OQ@vn5e3ljGs541rOuL6K2Rscv288GhmJOxNG72qK4H6DKXX8/v2UREcuwtN1T2J3PTndndSDxEVh888No@4H4Oeqi@DmUu/KMlN9JFRb0cpJAgyut/v/7tfz@Qc)

Fueue outputs:

```
9109ç8592ç«39ç«65328ç«99ç«111ç«110ç«115ç«111ç«108ç«101ç«46ç«108ç«111ç«103ç«40ç«39ç«39ç«112ç«97ç«99ç«107ç«97ç«103ç«101ç«32ç«109ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«59ç«105ç«109ç«112ç«111ç«114ç«116ç«32ç«34ç«102ç«109ç«116ç«34ç«59ç«102ç«117ç«110ç«99ç«32ç«109ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«40ç«41ç«32ç«123ç«102ç«109ç«116ç«46ç«80ç«114ç«105ç«110ç«116ç«40ç«34ç«117ç«115ç«105ç«110ç«103ç«32ç«83ç«121ç«115ç«116ç«101ç«109ç«59ç«99ç«108ç«97ç«115ç«115ç«32ç«80ç«114ç«111ç«103ç«114ç«97ç«109ç«123ç«115ç«116ç«97ç«116ç«105ç«99ç«32ç«118ç«111ç«105ç«100ç«32ç«77ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«40ç«115ç«116ç«114ç«105ç«110ç«103ç«91ç«93ç«32ç«97ç«114ç«103ç«115ç«41ç«32ç«123ç«67ç«111ç«110ç«115ç«111ç«108ç«101ç«46ç«87ç«114ç«105ç«116ç«101ç«40ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«127937ç«32ç«127815ç«128512ç«32ç«128292ç«112ç«117ç«98ç«108ç«105ç«99ç«32ç«99ç«108ç«97ç«115ç«115ç«32ç«77ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«32ç«123ç«112ç«117ç«98ç«108ç«105ç«99ç«32ç«115ç«116ç«97ç«116ç«105ç«99ç«32ç«118ç«111ç«105ç«100ç«32ç«109ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«40ç«83ç«116ç«114ç«105ç«110ç«103ç«91ç«93ç«32ç«97ç«114ç«103ç«115ç«41ç«123ç«83ç«121ç«115ç«116ç«101ç«109ç«46ç«111ç«117ç«116ç«46ç«112ç«114ç«105ç«110ç«116ç«40ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«35ç«105ç«110ç«99ç«108ç«117ç«100ç«101ç«32ç«60ç«105ç«111ç«115ç«116ç«114ç«101ç«97ç«109ç«62ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«110ç«105ç«110ç«116ç«32ç«109ç«97ç«105ç«110ç«40ç«41ç«123ç«115ç«116ç«100ç«58ç«58ç«99ç«111ç«117ç«116ç«32ç«60ç«60ç«32ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«72ç«65ç«73ç«32ç«49ç«46ç«50ç«32ç«66ç«84ç«87ç«43ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«110ç«86ç«73ç«83ç«73ç«66ç«76ç«69ç«32ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«32ç«60ç«60ç«32ç«92ç«39ç«39ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«92ç«39ç«39ç«32ç«60ç«60ç«32ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«91ç«43ç«43ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«43ç«43ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«91ç«43ç«43ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«45ç«46ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«91ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«62ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«60ç«93ç«62ç«43ç«46ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«43ç«46ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«45ç«46ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«32ç«60ç«60ç«32ç«92ç«39ç«39ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«92ç«39ç«39ç«32ç«60ç«60ç«32ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«110ç«75ç«84ç«72ç«88ç«66ç«89ç«69ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«59ç«125ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«41ç«59ç«125ç«125ç«128292ç«10071ç«65039ç«127817ç«92ç«92ç«34ç«41ç«59ç«125ç«125ç«34ç«41ç«125ç«39ç«39ç«41ç«39ç«
```

05AB1E outputs:

```
⎕←'Ｐconsole.log(''package main;import "fmt";func main() {fmt.Print("using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args) {Console.Write(\\"  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(\\\\\\"#include <iostream>\\\\\\\\nint main(){std::cout << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nVISIBLE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\'' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\'' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nKTHXBYE\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";}\\\\\\");}}❗️\\");}}")}'')'
```

APL (dzaima/APL) outputs:

```
Ｐconsole.log('package main;import "fmt";func main() {fmt.Print("using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args) {Console.Write(\\"  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(\\\\\\"#include <iostream>\\\\\\\\nint main(){std::cout << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nVISIBLE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nKTHXBYE\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";}\\\\\\");}}❗️\\");}}")}')
```

Charcoal outputs:

```
console.log('package main;import "fmt";func main() {fmt.Print("using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args) {Console.Write(\\"  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(\\\\\\"#include <iostream>\\\\\\\\nint main(){std::cout << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nVISIBLE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << \'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\' << \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nKTHXBYE\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";}\\\\\\");}}❗️\\");}}")}')
```

Node.js outputs:

```
package main;import "fmt";func main() {fmt.Print("using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args) {Console.Write(\"  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(\\\"#include <iostream>\\\\nint main(){std::cout << \\\\\\\"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\\\\\\\nVISIBLE \\\\\\\" << '\\\\\\\"' << \\\\\\\"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\\\\\\\" << '\\\\\\\"' << \\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\nKTHXBYE\\\\\\\";}\\\");}}❗️\");}}")}
```

Go outputs:

```
using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args) {Console.Write("  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(\"#include <iostream>\\nint main(){std::cout << \\\"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\\\nVISIBLE \\\" << '\\\"' << \\\"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\\\" << '\\\"' << \\\"\\\\nKTHXBYE\\\";}\");}}❗️");}}
```

C# outputs:

```
  public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print("#include <iostream>\nint main(){std::cout << \"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\nVISIBLE \" << '\"' << \"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\" << '\"' << \"\\nKTHXBYE\";}");}}❗️
```

Emojicode outputs:

```
public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print("#include <iostream>\nint main(){std::cout << \"HAI 1.2 BTW+\\nVISIBLE \" << '\"' << \"+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.\" << '\"' << \"\\nKTHXBYE\";}");}}
```

Java outputs:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){std::cout << "HAI 1.2 BTW+\nVISIBLE " << '"' << "+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------." << '"' << "\nKTHXBYE";}
```

C++ outputs:

```
HAI 1.2 BTW+
VISIBLE "+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------."
KTHXBYE
```

LOLCODE outputs:

```
+[----->+++<]>++.---.[--->+<]>--.[-->+++<]>+.-[--->++<]>.-[->++<]>-..+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>+.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.------.+.[->+++<]>.+++++.-----------.+++++++++.+++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.+.--[--->+<]>-.--[->++<]>.--[->++<]>-.+.++[->+++<]>++.+++++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.+[--->+<]>+++.++[->+++<]>.[-->+++<]>-.[->++++<]>--.-----.+++++.++++++.[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>.------------.++++++++.+++++.++[++>---<]>.+.---------.-[->++++<]>-.[->+++<]>-.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+++[->+++<]>+.---[->+++<]>-.------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.-.++++++++.+[-->+++++<]>.[----->++<]>-.--------.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.----..++++.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.---[->++<]>-.----.[->+++++<]>+..[-->+<]>-.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.+.-----------.++.----.+++++....[-->+++<]>--.-[--->++<]>---.++++.--[--->+<]>.+++++.++++++++++.[--->+<]>++.+++++++++++.++++++.[--->++<]>+++.++.----.-[->+++<]>.++++.--[->+++<]>....[->++++<]>--.-[->+++++<]>-...........--[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+++.-[->++<]>-.-[--->+<]>++.+++.+[-->+<]>++++.-------------.+[-->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>-.++.-------.+++++++++.++++++++.+.------.--[--->+<]>-.+++++.++++++++++.[++>---<]>.---------.+++++++.-[-->+++<]>-.--[->++<]>.-------------.[--->+<]>---.+.---.----.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++<]>.+++++++++++.-[--->++<]>+.-[---->+<]>+++.+++++++.>++++++++++.+[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++.----------.
```

Brainfuck outputs:

```
if 1 == 1
print("#include <stdio.h>\nint main() {printf("+34.chr+"print('/x/'+chr(39)+'##'+chr(34)+'GCPP'+chr(34)+',,,,@'+chr(39)+'rv\\\\n           ;!?lo</x')"+34.chr+");return 0;}")
end
```

Ruby outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {printf("print('/x/'+chr(39)+'##'+chr(34)+'GCPP'+chr(34)+',,,,@'+chr(39)+'rv\\n           ;!?lo</x')");return 0;}
```

C outputs:

```
print('/x/'+chr(39)+'##'+chr(34)+'GCPP'+chr(34)+',,,,@'+chr(39)+'rv\n           ;!?lo</x')
```

Python outputs:

```
/x/'##"GCPP",,,,@'rv
       ;!?lo</x
```

/// outputs:

```
'##"GCPP",,,,@'rv
           ;!?lo<
```

Fish (><>) outputs:

```
##"GCPP",,,,@
```

And Finally Befunge-93 outputs: PPCG

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXNitRAEH6VJh5mhqYL9LgZBhxZ2EGFhVlcpbOHmMmG1vyRnwUZBvQkHmQvgl5kLj7EPs@@gPMGYyfdSVfHUWRx6xA61VVffVXdVf3Gv/LLoBB5xdJsFe73QZaWWRxCnEXjUe4Hb/0oJIkvUlckeVZUxLlMKse9rNOgVY8nZC01cFqItBo7dSnSiCzflVWYuEHslyU5LbKo8JN1WfmVCMhVJlbkeeNZVtIn4hfEL6JSwjzRoc8LUYVjz3N22@sPZLf9/HG3/fZeLr78yOvXscRQwA0IWWsVRm95LS30taIEWV1B3lL1WnEeiDSI61VIpiKThEI/mXlaUmmmc5TkV0dHgfQm0ynxLHFOHi/IQ3hE5mfn1BtI@mKxXMyfHQ99WpjRQOmNDqBTzhqZUUqnF/IL8gd4q5H/at1tAlMbzU@zVisGQLm2p5Z5s9CiXBnr7VQkJaBMtCXlxqrbB96halvGBt4IQYOYlBpzk1L70yWBsmjcLS9MSm3oLYsjtfxQ/qxzUnU8kClnFgo39cH5mQR7b06phGRtOVAZGQpoKsb@VmuccmOEvP5Y3T6mXdbBEcj0DEsrPIr4j7cA8Lmak4D@7iLCGghzO0DNFB6prYOZmcNWJNUHers7Rhhc3R6aW3lYFw6AW1X@n5HVHgC@uAw3@n0W1O5qQNdPMcLtgwrCwIjVwRy1Ey7ogJ1laJWFsQM3bDbsonvoiX5GovZDUwoTRMOZqbBWNfv2tycmHsMzPM7xGFM2eGzrNjT92gMZQnd@e357zZ6enbycvzoemLkbvZi4m03zTN9@//rz5lq@3J@00plsRpP9/hc)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms thanks sorry for late reply

Answer (score 7):

## [Java](https://repl.it/FTjH/1) --> [C](https://repl.it/FTgJ/2) --> [Ruby](https://repl.it/FTgR/1) --> [///](https://repl.it/FThX/1) --> [Python 3](https://repl.it/FTh3/1) --> Batch --> [JavaScript](https://repl.it/FTi4/1) --> [BrainFuck](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LVstLS0-KzxdPi0tLS0tLi4tWy0tLS0tPis8XT4uKysrKy4$) (8 Languages)

---

Click the language names for the code through each execution, except for Batch, because I couldn't find an online interpreter for it.

---

```
class Main {public static void main(String[]args){System.out.println("int main(){printf(\"puts \\\"/code/print('echo console.log(\\\\\\\\'-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.\\\\\\\\\')')/code\\\"\");}");}}
```

Explanation:

```
Java outputs int main(){printf("puts \"/code/print('echo console.log(\\\\'-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.\\\\')')/code\"");}
C outputs puts "/code/print('echo console.log(\\'-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.\\')')/code"
Ruby outputs /code/print('echo console.log(\'-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.\')')/code
/// outputs print('echo console.log(\'-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.\')')
Python outputs echo console.log('-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.')
Batch outputs console.log('-[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.')
JavaScript outputs -[--->+<]>-----..-[----->+<]>.++++.
BrainFuck outputs PPCG
```

Comment: The Rhino interpreter for JavaScript can run the Python program, thus repeating a language. So whether this answer's valid or not depends on exactly how the rules on interpreters work.

Comment: @ais523 although `print()` works in JavaScript, it does not output anything, and in fact attempts to print the page, so I don't think that counts.

Comment: No, in Rhino, `print()` outputs its argument to standard output. (JavaScript the language doesn't really define a standard library; JavaScript + DOM does, but Rhino uses a different library.)

Comment: @ais523 Well, I'm not sure what exactly Rhino is. I've tested my code in Chrome, FF, IE, and repl.it, and it works the same in all.

Comment: If i understood the rules correctlu your score should be 1 as running the original code in BF ouptut PPCG

Comment: @Sefa Well, not exactly--I think there's always a null byte (ASCII 0) output first, because of the `.` in `console.log`.

Comment: @DLosc That's open for interpretation, but i tend to agree with you, i hadn't thought of it

Comment: @DLosc fishy, but I'll allow it :)

Comment: Good thing I didn't use alert ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Java -> BotEngine -> Treehugger -> Loader -> Batch -> Thue -> Microscript II -> BF -> ForceLang -> Javascript, 10 languages

**Java program:**

```
public class ManyLang {
    public static void main(String[]arg){
        int m=120;
        String e="++++++++[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^.";
        for(int i=1;i<e.length();i++){
            if(i==1){
                System.out.print("v");
            }
            else if(i%m==1&&i>1){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev");
                System.out.println("v                                                                                                                        <");
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(e.charAt(i-1));
        }
        System.out.println();System.out.print(">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeP");
    }
}
```

**BotEngine program:**

```
v++++++++[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ++++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.-
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 --^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>-
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 -.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 +^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 +.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 .---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 +++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.--
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 -^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.++
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 +^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 >>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 --^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeev
v                                                                                                                        <
 ^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^
>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeP
```

**Treehugger program:**

```
++++++++[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>+++.---^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^>++.--^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>--.++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>.^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>>---.+++^^^^^>>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^^^^^^^>>>>++.--^^^^>>>>.^^^^>>>>>>+++.---^^^^^^>>>>>>++.--^^^^^^>>>>>>----.++++^^^^^^>>>>>>>+.-^^^^^^^>>>>>>>-.+^^^^^^^.
```

**Loader program:**

```
printf "@echo%ca%c%c=~%c+[----->+++<]>++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.[--->++<]>+++.-----.---------.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.++.+[--->+<]>.+++++++++++.-------.+++++++++++++.++.+[--->+<]>+.-.+[->++<]>..-[----->+<]>.++++.+[-->+<]>+++.++.-------.%c." 32,58,58,34,34
printf "@echo%c%c%c=" 32,58,58
printf "@echo%c%c" 32,97
```

**Batch program:**

```
@echo a::=~"+[----->+++<]>++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.[--->++<]>+++.-----.---------.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.++.+[--->+<]>.+++++++++++.-------.+++++++++++++.++.+[--->+<]>+.-.+[->++<]>..-[----->+<]>.++++.+[-->+<]>+++.++.-------.".
@echo ::=
@echo a
```

**Thue program:**

```
a::=~"+[----->+++<]>++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.[--->++<]>+++.-----.---------.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.++.+[--->+<]>.+++++++++++.-------.+++++++++++++.++.+[--->+<]>+.-.+[->++<]>..-[----->+<]>.++++.+[-->+<]>+++.++.-------.".
::=
a
```

**Microscript II program:**

```
"+[----->+++<]>++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.[--->++<]>+++.-----.---------.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.++.+[--->+<]>.+++++++++++.-------.+++++++++++++.++.+[--->+<]>+.-.+[->++<]>..-[----->+<]>.++++.+[-->+<]>+++.++.-------.".
```

**BF program:**

```
+[----->+++<]>++.++++++.[->+++++<]>+++.[--->++<]>+++.-----.---------.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.++.+[--->+<]>.+++++++++++.-------.+++++++++++++.++.+[--->+<]>+.-.+[->++<]>..-[----->+<]>.++++.+[-->+<]>+++.++.-------.
```

**ForceLang program:**

```
io.write "alert('PPCG')"
```

**Javascript program:**

```
alert('PPCG')
```

Comment: Can you list the steps?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Done.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge (5 versions)

We start with the most recent version, **Befunge-109** (run with `cfunge -s 109`):

```
1k!!k@"1k!k@#;>@,k>'"'""r;@;"'"::''\"@_,#:>"'""\''::"'":''\"1j#@0"'""\'':"'":''\"::''\"'"::''\"GCPP"'""\'':"'":''\"::''\"'"::''\">:#,_@"'""\''::"'":''\"@j1A"'"::''\">:#,_@"'"";@r"'qk,@
```

Which outputs the following **Befunge-98** code ([Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=ckA7IkBfLCM6PiInIiJBMWpAIiciOjonJ1wiQF8sIzo+IiciIlwnJzo6IiciOicnXCJQUENHIiciIlwnJzo6IiciOicnXCIwQCNqMSInIjo6JydcIj46IyxfQCInIiI7QDtyIic+ayxAPjsjQGshazE&input=)):

```
r@;"@_,#:>"'""A1j@"'"::''\"@_,#:>"'""\''::"'":''\"PPCG"'""\''::"'":''\"0@#j1"'"::''\">:#,_@"'"";@;r"'>k,@>;#@k!k1
```

Which output the following **Befunge-97** code ([Try it online!](http://befunge-97-mtfi.tryitonline.net/#code=cjtAOyJAXywjOj4iJyIiMWojQDAiJyI6OicnXCJHQ1BQIiciOjonJ1wiPjojLF9AIiciIkBqMUEiPjojLF9A&input=)):

```
r;@;"@_,#:>"'""1j#@0"'"::''\"GCPP"'"::''\">:#,_@"'""@j1A">:#,_@
```

Which output the following **Befunge-96** code ([Try it online!](http://befunge-96-mtfi.tryitonline.net/#code=QTFqQCJAXywjOj4iJyIiUFBDRyInIiIwQCNqMSI+OiMsX0A&input=)):

```
A1j@"@_,#:>"'""PPCG"'""0@#j1">:#,_@
```

Which outputs the following **Befunge-93** ([Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=MWojQDAiR0NQUCI+OiMsX0A&input=)):

```
1j#@0"GCPP">:#,_@
```

Which outputs the string: `PPCG`

Each program will only run in the version of Befunge that it is targetting. If you try to run them in another version, they will exit immediately without outputting anything.

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis), nearly all versions of Befunge are now available online at [TIO](https://tio.run/).  The only exception is Befunge-109, for which you'll need *cfunge*, which can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cfunge/).

Answer (score 4):

## 11 languages, 536 bytes

### Bash -> Python 3 -> Go -> Lua -> Rust -> Java -> C99 -> Python 2 -> JavaScript -> Ruby -> Batch

#### Bash:

```
e="echo -n "
p(){
eval "for i in {1..$1}
do
$e'\'
done"
}
$e'import sys;print("package main\nimport \"fmt\"\nfunc main() {fmt.Printf(\"if 1 == 1 then print(\\\"fn main() {let s='
p 7
$e'"public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println('
p 15
$e'"#include <stdio.h>'
p 16
$e'nint main() {printf('
p 31
$e'"print '
p 63
$e"\"alert('puts "
p 128
$e"'@echo PPCG"
p 128
$e"'');"
p 63
$e'"'
p 31
$e'");}'
p 15
$e'");}}\\\\\\\";println!(\\\\\\\"{}\\\\\\\", s);}\\\") end\")}") if sys.version_info[0]==3 else exit()'
```

The `p` function reduces the code size by 497 bytes compared to typing all backslashes manually.

#### Python 3:

```
import sys;print("package main\nimport \"fmt\"\nfunc main() {fmt.Printf(\"if 1 == 1 then print(\\\"fn main() {let s=\\\\\\\"public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"#include <stdio.h>\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nint main() {printf(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"alert('puts \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'');\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");}}\\\\\\\";println!(\\\\\\\"{}\\\\\\\", s);}\\\") end\")}") if sys.version_info[0]==3 else exit()
```

The obligatory Python 2/3 differentiation.

#### Go:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {fmt.Printf("if 1 == 1 then print(\"fn main() {let s=\\\"public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\\\\\\\"#include <stdio.h>\\\\\\\\nint main() {printf(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"alert('puts \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'');\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");}\\\\\\\");}}\\\";println!(\\\"{}\\\", s);}\") end")}
```

#### Lua:

```
if 1 == 1 then print("fn main() {let s=\"public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\\\"#include <stdio.h>\\\\nint main() {printf(\\\\\\\"print \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"alert('puts \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'');\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\");}\\\");}}\";println!(\"{}\", s);}") end
```

Using `if 1 == 1 then` prevents Python compatibility.

#### Rust:

```
fn main() {let s="public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\"#include <stdio.h>\\nint main() {printf(\\\"print \\\\\\\"alert('puts \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'');\\\\\\\"\\\");}\");}}";println!("{}", s);}
```

#### Java:

```
public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println("#include <stdio.h>\nint main() {printf(\"print \\\"alert('puts \\\\\\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\\\\\'');\\\"\");}");}}
```

#### C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {printf("print \"alert('puts \\\\'@echo PPCG\\\\'');\"");}
```

#### Python 2:

```
print "alert('puts \\'@echo PPCG\\'');"
```

#### JavaScript:

```
alert('puts \'@echo PPCG\'');
```

#### Ruby:

```
puts '@echo PPCG'
```

#### Batch:

```
@echo PPCG
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## 11 languages (102 bytes)

I'm going to add more soon.

### Jelly -> Ruby -> ><> -> /// -> Batch -> Python 3 -> JavaScript -> J -> FOG -> Jolf -> Stacked

```
“puts <<q
/!/@ECHO print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")/!~
/0v
  >:1+$0g:'~'=?;o
q
```

Jelly ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU5BaUmxgo1NIZe@or6Dq7OHv0JBUWZeiYaSklJyfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaCulKigk@hqYaFgZWVobGulYm2prJVfmmJUoR6giZQsaa@Yh2XvkEZl4KCnZWhtopBupV6nbqtvXU@V@H//wA)) outputs:

```
puts <<q
/!/@ECHO print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")/!~
/0v
  >:1+$0g:'~'=?;o
q
```

Ruby ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@19QWlKsYGNTyKWvqO/g6uzhr1BQlJlXoqGkpJScn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGgrpSo4FNoqmFhYGVlaKxrZaKtqWyVX1qiFKGeoAlUrKmvWMelb1DGpaBgZ2WorWKQbqVep25rb53PVfj/PwA)) outputs:

```
/!/@ECHO print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")/!~
/0v
  >:1+$0g:'~'=?;o
```

[><>](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) (use this interpreter; it outputs spaces instead of null bytes for spaces) outputs:

```
/!/@ECHO print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")/!
```

/// ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@6@vqO/g6uzhr1BQlJlXoqGkpJScn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGgrpSo4FNoqmFhYGVlaKxrZaKtqWyVX1qiFKGeoAlUrKmv@P8/AA)) outputs:

```
@ECHO print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")
```

Batch outputs:

```
print("""console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)""")
```

Python 3 ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqGkpJScn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGgrpSo4FNoqmFhYGVlaKxrZaKtqWyVX1qiFKGeoAlUrPn/PwA)) outputs:

```
console.log(`'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'`)
```

JavaScript ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#@5@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGgrpSo4FNoqmFhYGVlaKxrZaKtqWyVX1qiFKGeoPn/PwA)) outputs:

```
'"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X'
```

J ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#S03OyFdQ0lPwcVPQ1atTMFCwUjD4r66UqOBTaKphYWBlZWisa2WiralslV9aohSh/l/zPwA)—only an approximation) yields:

```
"a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out"X
```

[FOG](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole/issues) prints:

```
a Lq5(80::13-:4+)#:out
```

Jolf ([Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=YSBMcTUoODA6OjEzLTo0KykjOm91dA)) outputs:

```
(80::13-:4+)#:out
```

Finally, Stacked ([Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)) outputs:

```
PPCG
```

Comment: It would be trivial to add Java.

Comment: @VoteToClose I don't .know Java,  but I'd bet it involves a lot of escaping.

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Batch -> [Powershell](http://%C2%B4https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@19elFmSqpuRX1yi4KDEVVBaUqxgY1PBVVCUmVeioaSklJiTWlSikVBQlJ9bUKKgrhQQ4OyupJ6gCZTS5KrgUnL4/x8A) -> [Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@19QWlKsYGNTwVVQlJlXoqGkpJSYk1pUopFQUJSfW1CioK4UEODsrqSeoAmU0uSq@P8fAA) -> [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqGkpJSYk1pUopFQUJSfW1CioK4UEODsrqSeoAmU0vz/HwA) -> JavaScript -> SQL -> [CJam](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@68UEODsrvT/PwA): 7 languages

### Windows Batch

```
@echo @"
@echo puts <<x
@echo print("""alert(`prompt '"PPCG"'`)""")
@echo x
@echo "@
```

### [Powershell](http://%C2%B4https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@19elFmSqpuRX1yi4KDEVVBaUqxgY1PBVVCUmVeioaSklJiTWlSikVBQlJ9bUKKgrhQQ4OyupJ6gCZTS5KrgUnL4/x8A)

```
@"
puts <<x
print("""alert(`prompt '"PPCG"'`)""")
x
"@
```

### [Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@19QWlKsYGNTwVVQlJlXoqGkpJSYk1pUopFQUJSfW1CioK4UEODsrqSeoAmU0uSq@P8fAA)

```
puts <<x
print("""alert(`prompt '"PPCG"'`)""")
x
```

### [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqGkpJSYk1pUopFQUJSfW1CioK4UEODsrqSeoAmU0vz/HwA)

```
print("""alert(`prompt '"PPCG"'`)""")
```

### JavaScript

```js
alert(`prompt '"PPCG"'`)
```

### SQL

```
prompt '"PPCG"'
```

### [CJam](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@68UEODsrvT/PwA)

```
"PPCG"
```

Comment: I think (in the title) you mean _Batch_, not _Bytch_?

Answer (score 2):

## 9 languages: Processing -> Java -> C -> Python 3 -> JavaScript (ES6) -> Octave -> Bash -> sed -> V, 160 bytes

```
print("class A{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(\"main(){printf(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"alert`disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')`\\\\\\\")#\\\");}\");}}");//
```

Right now my objective is to find and add languages where I don't need to escape quotes and stuff.

Processing outputs (note that the the Java program doesn't run in Processing and vice-versa)

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("main(){printf(\"print(\\\"alert`disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')`\\\")#\");}");}}
```

Java outputs:

```
main(){printf("print(\"alert`disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')`\")#");}
```

C outputs:

```
print("alert`disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')`")#
```

Python 3 (note that the python program won't work in Processing because of the comment and vice-versa) outputs:

```
alert`disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')`
```

JavaScript outputs:

```
disp('echo s/.*/iPPCG/')
```

Octave outputs:

```
echo s/.*/iPPCG/
```

Bash outputs:

```
s/.*/iPPCG/
```

sed outputs:

```
iPPCG
```

V outputs:

[`PPCG`](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@58ZEODs/v8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### [///](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@6@fpP@oYU6iflJOalGJhlJxak5qcol6QJCnX0iMkr1DQICze0KMkrqS5v//AA) to [Jelly](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU5iTmpRiYZScWpOanKJekCQp1@Ikr1DQICze4KSupLm////AQ) to Javascript to MS-SQL to QBasic to QBIC, 39 bytes, 6 languages

```
/b/“a/blert("select'PRINT\"?@PPCG`\"'")
```

Explanation:

```
///  Replaces the one 'b' with '“a', returns 
“alert("select'PRINT\"?@PPCG`\"'")

Jelly just sees everything as a string literal and prints it (shamelessly stole this trick from @ConoroBrien)
alert("select'PRINT\"?@PPCG`\"'")

Javascript posts this in a dialog window:
select'PRINT"?@PPCG`"'

MSSQL then selects:
PRINT"?@PPCG`"'")

QBasic puts this on the screen:
?@PPCG`

QBIC then prints 'PPCG'
```

QBIC and QBasic have many similarities. However, these lines of code are not cross-compatible: QBasic accepts the `?` as shorthand for `PRINT`, but does not know what to do with the `@` and the backtick. QBIC will interpret the `PRINT` line as a reference to 5 different string variables and `P$R$I$N$T$` is not a valid statement.

Comment: I love the `blert` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly -> kavod -> BrainF*** -> PostScript -> Elixir -> Python 3 -> Haskell -> Haystack -> MY

Score - <s>4 5 6</s> 9

<s>All</s> Almost all of these languages were chosen randomly.

I tried figuring out how to print something in the randomly chosen language unless:

1. I *really* didn’t want to do it,
2. It broke the rules,
3. It had bad documentation

End result (after a lot of going back and forth and back and forth):

```
“7Äỵ\T^HẈȮ⁺y?ƤṚÄȦṇŻ%ẠṠḄ®ọ?Ḥñ2XBBaȮÄȤ3ḃɗ¤ȧ:6Ẇİ/'ȯḅvịĊḥṬƬ¤]9½ỌỊf£x⁼ḃƑz@ỴiŒQƒ[Ḥḅ⁽d'ẉ'IiƒnP^j]ṂX8æ6ḣṢż¥ƈżḅ⁻0@dñ0ṡhṖ¹'¤5Ɠ6Ḍ×Q7ʂḣṚȤ)ẇ+ñ\ȮG$§Ḍ©M2ż°Q⁵)gŻCHḅWṃuḢ"h.ÐeṡḳƊkjĖẠ<ṣ⁸⁽ƭ¡(ĖZ,ḅẇr⁸J¡Sẹ⁼vĊƒ4ẋRuİ< ɦ¢DH#ḄrsßṆṇẊịȧṂ\ṀþTtkẠṙẉƘyƝƭĿ€hX¢ṅṣøɲbẆ>Ḋ]ẸN/ÐẒṭdṡÄÑ°Ġ'-Ɓ&+ñȥUC-ƈ&Xỵ-ṚṾȧḋGẎcḥpḷị2ç¡ŀ7⁻ṁŻ0ḃƇ"Ċ Ṛɲịɠ9ẋ¿°ɓĿȯ^?_aß{ċK)ĠƑ^F½:¶ñFṛ2ɦ,ṭFT|dJɦȤẇ×jṭ⁻Ẹð8SCḃ⁼ⱮŀẸṙ⁺¶ḟṪbOḲ")^0ḣ7Ç7ȷẒʋQlḣ*ṡḢçĿ×{ḤẎʠṠṙieBȦyṃŻȷ8dẋiʋⱮ{ƭœŀ1ḣẉfw=w⁾ġṭ¬ ĿƁ*}⁼£ƤḊ⁶Ḃ;ɓ¥z÷µ}ḟM¿PẈ³y>A8ɼ½Ỵ[3IṁPẈ²Ḍṫ+ḣ ƤẈuxGḣȷƑḤŻċ⁼½XŻƇṀÑ9ṡ²"ỊẆj¥<Ọḃ⁸^ȮȥƓȯḌ<ĖẋẈė`Ẉy!=yḂṫẆæṇCQȷ°ḍ15(Ḟ³eọ¿ßẏJṭhœẆɓb4¿-Ṗ5>ç⁽?§>⁽fU8xlŻ,^ṣƒ@)Bị⁺cÑŻ²¡ṚƤ?ḣ&1yƁŻWÇut-ẒḂ5mṖḃŒṇ⁼ƙNḅẏḌṢḢṇṂİUþı¶5?Ḍḃı#¶©ḅGḋDṂȧṣɠḷ(%a_ʂ?_°=©⁷⁻⁼⁹×Ẏ¶@'ẒȮuȤrÆỊɱ⁼3ẹṪ¬ȥjɼ®Ṃ⁶O$ʂḌḍṠȷRʋȥ1\ġ÷ⱮṢėµḣṆḲṡḄ&⁶⁾Ṅi²ẈẉṛÐḞ⁹⁷"iṁṬñŀ,Ġc⁸fŻİċµ^ȤṠ2ß⁷ñBȥɼ>ÐV÷ṛ5ḅḃẠƙṣbɱCạṇṅṬ>Aø0ẏMẆṾƘIʋỤBIɠJṘ÷ṁḟȤkẹ)ġo8[ʠṂ²ḷ+§ḲP5Ɲu&ðß .ṇɓẠHỵ`ġÐJ©4(\ỴmZḃæ,ẸÄN(ẋṾ'!ð%ÐB#.d~IQ½N>°Ṙw£ḋ~-¢zƤḷḅBṃo5Ạŀ¢væḳBı€÷ạİ Vṫ⁻`ðßoĊŻBqƙPɠḶ_3ȤAŀ⁾ḄƝOM'ḄṢ⁶H,ḥ%ṙt¡ĿịƊ@ƤwƘ$*żḢGżĊ5ẓ⁷ẉ%°ŀḌWẈṣṾịÐxEėkḄh⁺dnð⁻ȯ(EÐŀ⁷.MṣⱮỊ⁹ḃœÐṄ%a¢F¡ṅ,ṆFÑ²Ḃ#ÐƓ'F3`Ȧ4SȤṭḋṢṖ-æʂ'ÄƁḞBṁ7øæỌFjẈTṣLtÑḞɦ½NḅḤƭVvİigPæÄ²ʂIẠẆdƬrạ⁸3ÇḤĊ.5%=TrĿẉḤḤ.Ȥ?©A7HġṆ6¹ÄṀ.ḋWṭ"B⁺ʋrñyS²ẏẆÐɦ§Ỵ?ṃjɱɼİXȥ\ṭ$Q¿¦ṭr⁹ækẏḞ2Ñ¥ÑṚ-wḋyƇȮḋḟƭ°£V£#cṁṪÑḞƙ4=AGĠ`ʂsƁÑȤ|⁴ɦġƬḟEÑ&ḃƊġ1ȤbṠ(5lḟ'C¿⁻DḌṚṭ®İċƈġ|Ṁ¢ẎĠ!³hɓ@ṭ7dW⁸Ỵʂƥ_ƒḋẋẸg,ʠS>ẒẉẓɦkĖỌ[ỵwÞdṪḂÑɱṅÞoḶṚṙ¹ị¦Ċ`Ṅ⁷¿Ḣ6c\Ƈ€açb½@HŒẏṾⱮ/]ḊḲṙ[/ı^ȤḷClAọẒZÑPƭƬmṣ Ba_¤Ẹ⁴Ḳ⁵hqÞ<⁵ṖṂ,ṪḊṾCB⁵ḋẇɲḢ]h@*?NLṁṾṚṆƭƑḞṁHẠḥ⁵ḍ^(,c³wÆç2Q/sGƤEt¬ȥÞ!Ƒ;gsṗṭɗḲzaeḍ7_Þ5ɲạṣẇNƲPøzĠɲ¢vỤȷ³qẎqḳẆıYṆȧ£⁽Ḅɦḟ31ẉỊ2µÑɲẎƙ;XĿØ=Kṁ÷oṭGŻʋẎðƘ°.}¬.®Ḳ[N_ẇrḂḂṡɲĠȥ1ẆĊ>§ÆœƓḃɗẒḄ÷µẈ¬þaḷ<ɗⱮʠỴƘU=.½@ṇQ:¹ØȯƝøaÐȤⱮÆƈN64Ṣṙ3ạĠṛ€QȤyıṖ0|ẠdƊɼuṪ"Ɱ)ḄyẉHẎḅ©Ṙ⁺ẹ5FɗµiȧĿṾ@ẹÇ£}5Aw⁷Tỵ^ḃlĿṇØṁĠ®Za½ėḥḥ²ṖⱮ7ßẋpḅỵI¹uọȥW6H¥qṂ#⁽Ḣ=Æ²¿ɗỌJḃgM§"m⁾Ḣ!IuƒIn%H>[pẠgI$ẠPıTuKa,ƙƇ0¬ȧ÷=⁷aṪƇṙɲṀ°ṙṡa;]³²,\ẇUPl$¬SỊỴọÄ$×:@ṢZ!³O⁻rnṭBṠṾṆøɲṡ⁶&c½;⁴¢ėḞⱮ;ı⁻ĠÞœz⁽%⁶P÷Ṛḷ{Ññɠḟµ4¢ṣuı,¬ʠkẆḷUbḋɗḳHẏṾẓgsç76ƥ.ỌṁọḄU⁼ı*þạ½DE*ḷuœṬʠż~¢⁵Øɓȧ5ỊḲƓðƝƇÑ¥İcḥỴƈ&®Ẏỵ§4T¹ƥIÐkjI×?fFĿ#⁼JL)7ḅṁ&,hṄŀwßƈḂɱⱮX⁸6§⁺+(hɲ|Q€rɦẏ¢oḳ= ḳṭẉḋ\ỊMwĖṡ'Ȧ"Ƥ[⁹⁷ṚþṄzoỊẋ¹ɱɗVɓẋ5ġç¢ɲƙFÆDȯ5⁷Ạ|®HÑ*uPþṣ⁺ḟṗG)ḍvT¹/aỴƊʂṪ¡ÞER'œḢøŒẒ1w^ṀṀ|⁼¥ Ƒ3n³Ḍƭ⁾ị⁸IŒḊ¶ŻĿ²¶}⁼ṙBỌ{h.ɱœṚ"^Ẉɲ7+ċ.\ṙŀb+ġÄṬƁiFṄỤṾMÑƲṂ¬¢ṙoẈmƬ2°;®ṄqḢgḢġɱƇıọẒk⁹g$ẎɼƲ⁻Deç®⁻µḂẉAƁ¬PṬ¤ṘịÇ¹#pɗ⁾œỵ(ȥ⁶⁻xė#ĿL1ė:¢&¢İLẇØṙHNṃƭƥ%³,1QV¡y⁺³1ḥċhbḣḳṂȯZM(ƇNØ®%LṂ:z=æØyNÇƤṗḲñ¢E⁵XŻ6ðO3ṃ⁸Ṣƥ|w_¶Ṅ¬&ṁ⁺ḷİṚ(ṙċƬƙæ4Ƈƈḳ0ỤȦḥ¥nɱ®®ß⁺Qwḷ!⁹k⁵×£ɼ¢ÆọMẆ¹ȷ⁹;dÞŻỴ:ṙµɼt)NWɲ&øɗ^ỵƑ.$ḷṬv¶ẇỤḊṙ¥¦^tQṅṆṫµḅeaɠ&#ḌÞAṢzÑ%dƝƭ¬ı2ÄƲṄḞ©¡⁾}ɦQzȮxḃ7Ɠ»
```

---

### Jelly (New!)

```
“7Äỵ\T^HẈȮ⁺y?ƤṚÄȦṇŻ%ẠṠḄ®ọ?Ḥñ2XBBaȮÄȤ3ḃɗ¤ȧ:6Ẇİ/'ȯḅvịĊḥṬƬ¤]9½ỌỊf£x⁼ḃƑz@ỴiŒQƒ[Ḥḅ⁽d'ẉ'IiƒnP^j]ṂX8æ6ḣṢż¥ƈżḅ⁻0@dñ0ṡhṖ¹'¤5Ɠ6Ḍ×Q7ʂḣṚȤ)ẇ+ñ\ȮG$§Ḍ©M2ż°Q⁵)gŻCHḅWṃuḢ"h.ÐeṡḳƊkjĖẠ<ṣ⁸⁽ƭ¡(ĖZ,ḅẇr⁸J¡Sẹ⁼vĊƒ4ẋRuİ< ɦ¢DH#ḄrsßṆṇẊịȧṂ\ṀþTtkẠṙẉƘyƝƭĿ€hX¢ṅṣøɲbẆ>Ḋ]ẸN/ÐẒṭdṡÄÑ°Ġ'-Ɓ&+ñȥUC-ƈ&Xỵ-ṚṾȧḋGẎcḥpḷị2ç¡ŀ7⁻ṁŻ0ḃƇ"Ċ Ṛɲịɠ9ẋ¿°ɓĿȯ^?_aß{ċK)ĠƑ^F½:¶ñFṛ2ɦ,ṭFT|dJɦȤẇ×jṭ⁻Ẹð8SCḃ⁼ⱮŀẸṙ⁺¶ḟṪbOḲ")^0ḣ7Ç7ȷẒʋQlḣ*ṡḢçĿ×{ḤẎʠṠṙieBȦyṃŻȷ8dẋiʋⱮ{ƭœŀ1ḣẉfw=w⁾ġṭ¬ ĿƁ*}⁼£ƤḊ⁶Ḃ;ɓ¥z÷µ}ḟM¿PẈ³y>A8ɼ½Ỵ[3IṁPẈ²Ḍṫ+ḣ ƤẈuxGḣȷƑḤŻċ⁼½XŻƇṀÑ9ṡ²"ỊẆj¥<Ọḃ⁸^ȮȥƓȯḌ<ĖẋẈė`Ẉy!=yḂṫẆæṇCQȷ°ḍ15(Ḟ³eọ¿ßẏJṭhœẆɓb4¿-Ṗ5>ç⁽?§>⁽fU8xlŻ,^ṣƒ@)Bị⁺cÑŻ²¡ṚƤ?ḣ&1yƁŻWÇut-ẒḂ5mṖḃŒṇ⁼ƙNḅẏḌṢḢṇṂİUþı¶5?Ḍḃı#¶©ḅGḋDṂȧṣɠḷ(%a_ʂ?_°=©⁷⁻⁼⁹×Ẏ¶@'ẒȮuȤrÆỊɱ⁼3ẹṪ¬ȥjɼ®Ṃ⁶O$ʂḌḍṠȷRʋȥ1\ġ÷ⱮṢėµḣṆḲṡḄ&⁶⁾Ṅi²ẈẉṛÐḞ⁹⁷"iṁṬñŀ,Ġc⁸fŻİċµ^ȤṠ2ß⁷ñBȥɼ>ÐV÷ṛ5ḅḃẠƙṣbɱCạṇṅṬ>Aø0ẏMẆṾƘIʋỤBIɠJṘ÷ṁḟȤkẹ)ġo8[ʠṂ²ḷ+§ḲP5Ɲu&ðß .ṇɓẠHỵ`ġÐJ©4(\ỴmZḃæ,ẸÄN(ẋṾ'!ð%ÐB#.d~IQ½N>°Ṙw£ḋ~-¢zƤḷḅBṃo5Ạŀ¢væḳBı€÷ạİ Vṫ⁻`ðßoĊŻBqƙPɠḶ_3ȤAŀ⁾ḄƝOM'ḄṢ⁶H,ḥ%ṙt¡ĿịƊ@ƤwƘ$*żḢGżĊ5ẓ⁷ẉ%°ŀḌWẈṣṾịÐxEėkḄh⁺dnð⁻ȯ(EÐŀ⁷.MṣⱮỊ⁹ḃœÐṄ%a¢F¡ṅ,ṆFÑ²Ḃ#ÐƓ'F3`Ȧ4SȤṭḋṢṖ-æʂ'ÄƁḞBṁ7øæỌFjẈTṣLtÑḞɦ½NḅḤƭVvİigPæÄ²ʂIẠẆdƬrạ⁸3ÇḤĊ.5%=TrĿẉḤḤ.Ȥ?©A7HġṆ6¹ÄṀ.ḋWṭ"B⁺ʋrñyS²ẏẆÐɦ§Ỵ?ṃjɱɼİXȥ\ṭ$Q¿¦ṭr⁹ækẏḞ2Ñ¥ÑṚ-wḋyƇȮḋḟƭ°£V£#cṁṪÑḞƙ4=AGĠ`ʂsƁÑȤ|⁴ɦġƬḟEÑ&ḃƊġ1ȤbṠ(5lḟ'C¿⁻DḌṚṭ®İċƈġ|Ṁ¢ẎĠ!³hɓ@ṭ7dW⁸Ỵʂƥ_ƒḋẋẸg,ʠS>ẒẉẓɦkĖỌ[ỵwÞdṪḂÑɱṅÞoḶṚṙ¹ị¦Ċ`Ṅ⁷¿Ḣ6c\Ƈ€açb½@HŒẏṾⱮ/]ḊḲṙ[/ı^ȤḷClAọẒZÑPƭƬmṣ Ba_¤Ẹ⁴Ḳ⁵hqÞ<⁵ṖṂ,ṪḊṾCB⁵ḋẇɲḢ]h@*?NLṁṾṚṆƭƑḞṁHẠḥ⁵ḍ^(,c³wÆç2Q/sGƤEt¬ȥÞ!Ƒ;gsṗṭɗḲzaeḍ7_Þ5ɲạṣẇNƲPøzĠɲ¢vỤȷ³qẎqḳẆıYṆȧ£⁽Ḅɦḟ31ẉỊ2µÑɲẎƙ;XĿØ=Kṁ÷oṭGŻʋẎðƘ°.}¬.®Ḳ[N_ẇrḂḂṡɲĠȥ1ẆĊ>§ÆœƓḃɗẒḄ÷µẈ¬þaḷ<ɗⱮʠỴƘU=.½@ṇQ:¹ØȯƝøaÐȤⱮÆƈN64Ṣṙ3ạĠṛ€QȤyıṖ0|ẠdƊɼuṪ"Ɱ)ḄyẉHẎḅ©Ṙ⁺ẹ5FɗµiȧĿṾ@ẹÇ£}5Aw⁷Tỵ^ḃlĿṇØṁĠ®Za½ėḥḥ²ṖⱮ7ßẋpḅỵI¹uọȥW6H¥qṂ#⁽Ḣ=Æ²¿ɗỌJḃgM§"m⁾Ḣ!IuƒIn%H>[pẠgI$ẠPıTuKa,ƙƇ0¬ȧ÷=⁷aṪƇṙɲṀ°ṙṡa;]³²,\ẇUPl$¬SỊỴọÄ$×:@ṢZ!³O⁻rnṭBṠṾṆøɲṡ⁶&c½;⁴¢ėḞⱮ;ı⁻ĠÞœz⁽%⁶P÷Ṛḷ{Ññɠḟµ4¢ṣuı,¬ʠkẆḷUbḋɗḳHẏṾẓgsç76ƥ.ỌṁọḄU⁼ı*þạ½DE*ḷuœṬʠż~¢⁵Øɓȧ5ỊḲƓðƝƇÑ¥İcḥỴƈ&®Ẏỵ§4T¹ƥIÐkjI×?fFĿ#⁼JL)7ḅṁ&,hṄŀwßƈḂɱⱮX⁸6§⁺+(hɲ|Q€rɦẏ¢oḳ= ḳṭẉḋ\ỊMwĖṡ'Ȧ"Ƥ[⁹⁷ṚþṄzoỊẋ¹ɱɗVɓẋ5ġç¢ɲƙFÆDȯ5⁷Ạ|®HÑ*uPþṣ⁺ḟṗG)ḍvT¹/aỴƊʂṪ¡ÞER'œḢøŒẒ1w^ṀṀ|⁼¥ Ƒ3n³Ḍƭ⁾ị⁸IŒḊ¶ŻĿ²¶}⁼ṙBỌ{h.ɱœṚ"^Ẉɲ7+ċ.\ṙŀb+ġÄṬƁiFṄỤṾMÑƲṂ¬¢ṙoẈmƬ2°;®ṄqḢgḢġɱƇıọẒk⁹g$ẎɼƲ⁻Deç®⁻µḂẉAƁ¬PṬ¤ṘịÇ¹#pɗ⁾œỵ(ȥ⁶⁻xė#ĿL1ė:¢&¢İLẇØṙHNṃƭƥ%³,1QV¡y⁺³1ḥċhbḣḳṂȯZM(ƇNØ®%LṂ:z=æØyNÇƤṗḲñ¢E⁵XŻ6ðO3ṃ⁸Ṣƥ|w_¶Ṅ¬&ṁ⁺ḷİṚ(ṙċƬƙæ4Ƈƈḳ0ỤȦḥ¥nɱ®®ß⁺Qwḷ!⁹k⁵×£ɼ¢ÆọMẆ¹ȷ⁹;dÞŻỴ:ṙµɼt)NWɲ&øɗ^ỵƑ.$ḷṬv¶ẇỤḊṙ¥¦^tQṅṆṫµḅeaɠ&#ḌÞAṢzÑ%dƝƭ¬ı2ÄƲṄḞ©¡⁾}ɦQzȮxḃ7Ɠ»
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##JVcJUxPZFv4ryI4iyhJwRHZlcQRhROWJgizK5ooigjhFYiRMgkpIlSG8JyQhSzkTYhKEdKdZqu7t3OrmXzR/xPednioFTe5yzvmWc@7koydP5n79Ol38Xw23G8re/d6BdiOzrMVPrZm5BhEy5A1u1yKG7MgqBUbGb8h@Q7KzuKF8ajCkEE9W9DU3D2lxLApVGtIH3ctCWvRytZFZUhMXirQfhvTxjaG4VKchhQ05JmIs9OA3dmgoK4bifMy2355aD7BPuOcbDeXnRHatR6z142TsO7UejhYZmb@KOibE2rPugckHhmzru8Qj1Ya0bcjB7AELi@XsgblUudg4ypMXDTkwbshfmVzEQhbhwcoV7u2pObGZWza0UImRcZzjyftavC2fRfE1@95ZgZMSPafWvZKxrNLSjvPuGvKHGUMK5o6X8dVHONSQdoVzalL9ihpcMeTtU6uE8MQOCxSrX@@VYgvOncan11nglpGRkdUb1SnWqoyM648ZNXElR4@w4NX2PFRv@hXfMuQl1NTIOFEbLYq87hvyIj/qfT1lFtmHtMX6nPgmdtTjU1tsvI8FDfkjLuaSnhpGdesNyfnAyEhdF/iqkVkz5J1RhMnt3M0Sqr/ovLAWIk0tfLvlvFgu7AO055G/IR/hNsnVZmQ@jwCRF4aURgQVPMoC2cUalNGQrVnlIiHiyFWdOdijp7BC9/@GTNgxS@ge9Vj7MdAwOMS33qmu30tUv3APtLLDy2yfJ1sN@b8VeqQU8bT2Loxe1yNaCJXh3kl8QsdnJJ64dKsFF6BEp8l4dhEfIWHwje0bEgrz9/BNQ0rllgwgiu0a7qjR0kjwxNXzBP8/a2IR5FH1mHvfEU8yn09MVsq@iUfNWmQOyGUVLX1pFPFOnLhwxTuxk/VkF8uJApm/Hs/WzZ5aj9QAAmKxHPVYWM@@RyxsG2yXnKdWRGGr1T0sPM/TbO89Yupkx90QBdudq2@6pB8Qe3/2V3agVObHKbDIkP85h/NzcEZmeeZtG/6tpYUbAWYV1UXHH/ZlFeEglN2/IQmWyoUAAOQkC18hNVBBpAEtroWFh2SzcoXI5sJxqvchfs6dqZtDZLgImzgpsqVHS7OEIX0qtxQb0ibbfQRVsmOQK/PlOrIbz3qwVPcMV7FjgP/VUs@jIG0Di9bj1@Pbl94@ySqlAyCVWGssaQbKAGGEu7MKSzGUZ0OEoPHtwvI5AU7c5Y6Z1@eJapLN8hTHIeIseOdAcsLXZSrgi1mJIAAicss2NXGbH6lJtm9poG@kD2oyj@2z71iMCrmuYgmRf1uHqaSLC4YGT2wNgyxRx76fWtNgC1HEKnMvQGb7jfCCNS0@o4Wm@RJqpyfxdSW0BsqwmBaeBDJxnAgEb@aT4HHhJzBDS/9x4tLC5ffVAE@DDghQ9bI90xCWwDSTUfZCbAMtDNk@AUAzy2AKqAxtSZsIAeHkTgBvOBhPZhdLVf8I0HoMbBOqi@0NgOSyv4JvYR1PNmth/aCer97haRxhocpIHyBr4UOqw3qyxcgEzPpAz7H6Ji5dROU6ARXUKdY7TlyGEmru0P3AcJ2OsIKCWgjGIJeogeeX@onvNmJd@hw5WKrbIr7NFPIE38opw7k6UPe3Q/APkfDqdfa9qvg@CPv0HqLgUCYUaO8qJmrJR0VneKKArzbnlY3@2dHDDrvqQSh5fZZtA54/z7PgPIkijRSaoavnFpycXWTBN@CftNusJmFNiDATUBM5d8BMQPaQ4niuOrNK80vh6yZk9wcrtVBTdpHKK9nFt5udRfgNGFDydlhnuADifc0C6jEoKJyNIjQr1vPPkrEH27IHqhPXelBZQFLAEjAMaeUuISQDwCNs4atvr6neKZw5DgKPPuMJxKH9KL7GV@nSdFknGTaAV6BumWjrAa6yvWCIBVuJ6B9hV0utcE7U1JbHV4WnqLXyoRapukW47qAURGr563keObEVcbsAIpsoiLWGS6iEstI6iXh6ccuN1xya34TXH5qKkEJi584bNTEx1s0j3M5SJ7YOMvjM0qiITaNwYFEld2Cd6iyzFNT1TqMIYB71v1CZFmpg35tq2smrlqqZjA4tL5YhHLSnndxmJHvimubJuVvE2C9kC6u4OQqwG4DWpJ7UD9REnxZGb9nJ74F5wzV2pklRkSlTrJsVSDqMkOWN87M4d044tDilK22htSXY9h22nTdi8v5vMzHhq6pralP9D09sr4SVu7XQwqn1px5RAyKGTde4u5Bah1MNlGuhYWii2ALX3ipqYcfA5KppDxtkvHESjlhWAwtICb0t81n1n2G747qnEV/XjN5FYZDHiU2EB8UahURWKI2Vnvhv1ZMJoUgZjx6ZgkkqK/1g@yzfRAf8Gwhyt54EqHzzObhn3udjMnjCIqrzIXAHJdgxuFU9cl84wOAhHh1mh43tcDMURT4CVS48QCswvcHXf0FNkr6ldMuTJhgsLr/H3d1iR8Tggts5zUODDKaPceAnNmCIGH/JN6/gN1mkbCs1Y3Li2JZm@pAycaClSsEH441nG7pumNU9MsNcwqFUZXzUTiyRwuaOTwPFpSNsd5Yv8WhFz4VXbSJ07TU5Ht88I9y1Y68M2Yui6V7cPz/0CBtqBvmmBZeQz6DnObpEqptL86pfT0G8sBc0jt2XKPpLyJhGteR/cLsWZZhrDqEjHfLeqiynIivOCraHiuKwz8JX24e@u173OyLk6ee4tC2rwK8yn3lCrLNE2XsWK4MJS6n@rkEaiKhhUc8K6CnVDw@mu5z1LMqXsh7hMedFs6PYqdVSL43xoyGU@oruBQowOuWnWL9dVwZ44Gw9l6GBde2H@MalIb6qhbCGL4nlruoqU6C@SrIiuON/gWqPFppTwYOvFxdQy1Hh1A9mgEUu9pTgwjkkhyJ/hkrRj@R1iAkGa2nFALs3oWG8ACiN@IQ72PZ7SxNGhnQvWDaAmJ/Qlw6@jiKofha/N8QOVS@Nt1IYQpS/4oYaasKuF2QByl4Hk2dAHC18t7qdhV@CFHlmmYN1fAmd9hg1UFau4@CxThbNfWraZPBMx4xY63hW0F7f/wLxj3Xk42e3muyd@X2oVPiE4yIYEOXpOgQ2hLxotPABJagpQfOjHBiqfcB2War0PoC43f0kn8Vu0cSh/EQs3J7PvZdR0@A9qO4mtDn9DGg2m4MUyLhEYybOgEMXjrDDWpCbBSnJTSRXC9@3Kqqfb2Y988ikAKu6qVFtALl33M2T5PpbbK@KhtbtGTVZymIn/inqcFL69jA0QFzdbf9XbtDx2CserakW4TIahKAHqEyy30Z7V5NnORYE2OHVa2exeQYjjYyzsgd/MrSPPb6ue7SohfKSUsIDFn4TDvI0NUHjLdFnuRCEBM7KHotW9TJZhDv46tRkB/c2PG5VjwHFwfUbJTUElWwtLMXrwZ5dnOVbYhnMxYyRjPfBi6oZRqfMueJxPbXQA3ZNQyKZLywIi9mtyyEVoU@QcbvQa52ds7AlOVCkRXJFqP/f@YFeUjRezD835z4Xk@HP3jvUrV0WdOooC@op4WvlS1e1Hxaz3fkXWLydu8/OdNPObaIoDcjeNhD40xvkcmGIMnRi2MEIFOCb1/4oQoEwHkvkZWvlsxjuFvFngQbQcI5wVz5juzBhsUMko3lP6sBKycn2Mcocg4z7NAqDP5gGV96Nl@lJKvhG7gC0qadqzqmuMjQTX3Zx@BxCttODzjqBmR9PR3TKo07uFikaTmKEvO85dj0VsQqWqKXJzA63CY7hrxrQk8IBcZpuOoX6jIHdn/UDkaIu8Qi1wPtToRnNhqI2CSuLdeMu@Ky8Tg3fweS8F7AI6xHCU/aKtbA5vSlvVW@eenyjXPVeZsFCMDZxgx4fUKqvvQstEf4aLmC7peU9d1hgjp4cu3gVhFXX@DCNg4SiTftxr7NYOLr4OosXwJ1tl@fr0LvX57q4g97D5LI8yYLXQD@M9NU8cbMSR1O/koMivDA7iHeMbGexQvDJhCytQpEbxQgCLS8mfDxSJRxEr92LZMUR8o3wMz3J4ixOI2SmB704fQZlmSKKe9k2JtsgzbyfaEpksobZWK4dhf4U4H@Z@tuefvC6pOuuniqEcr0DKIpwl@XT6CbH3iCgjIMQoj7kY2EWGXjdY46fGDn/oTJ/fDSk@wvz6LW82YQ85rm7YJRenyymJisw8aQIY7wxvjN4wtF7PdIzr8XfwrNqhIcpv379Hw).
Made with [this.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/113599)

### kavod

```
43#43#91#45#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#45#45#45#46#45#45#45#91#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#45#45#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#45#46#43#43#91#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#46#43#43#43#43#43#46#45#46#45#46#43#91#45#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#43#43#43#46#43#43#46#43#43#43#91#45#62#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#43#43#46#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#46#43#43#43#43#43#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#43#91#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#46#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#91#45#45#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#45#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#43#43#43#43#43#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#43#91#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#43#43#43#43#43#46#45#46#45#45#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#91#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#43#43#43#46#45#45#46#91#45#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#43#43#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#46#46#46#46#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#45#45#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#46#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#45#45#91#45#45#62#43#43#43#60#93#62#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#43#43#46#46#46#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#91#43#43#62#45#60#93#62#45#45#45#46#91#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#43#43#46#46#46#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#91#43#43#62#45#60#93#62#45#45#45#46#45#45#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#46#43#43#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#43#43#46#46#46#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#91#43#43#62#45#60#93#62#45#45#45#46#91#45#45#45#62#43#60#93#62#43#46#43#43#43#43#43#43#46#43#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#43#46#91#45#45#45#45#45#62#43#43#60#93#62#43#43#46#46#46#46#91#45#62#43#43#43#43#43#43#60#93#62#45#46#45#91#43#43#62#45#60#93#62#45#45#45#46#43#43#91#43#43#62#45#45#45#
```

Made with some python code I wrote ([link](https://tio.run/##pVG7DoMwDPwVpA4ksuKlY1t@JGKrqtIhQUAl@vU0sZ0HHYsBoZzuzr54/CxP787btt4GN74XpS/jNLhFtacWX35wys7LpPx0V7PWDz81czO4Zu01BIbeNgBrqDq49l34Y/hsONERgSpjjEbYFhEKJzwMExoheoGVEUK24hKZdCAlC7GeCDF1JgtkGvNMVeKTDIuKYtSJbN1HnPcxUtjST/KENlmToEw1SLUft/YSQqpfojjnSaJ7ufR0K5IdokNtEDMCdEaWaPfLOeS12z3y8o@OVe/9T68wRjwZ8wU)). [TIO](https://HWj1dhhKsPGfj2539aiOdysQI9AXg0gETZDSCN9wsLOp2k1vO6IyvwYL8YP4p5PnYqQBOnVejRv0nHqmeRfNEZnPsjYP3wTA3P)

### Brainf*** (New!)

```
++[------>+<]>---.---[->++<]>-.++++++.---[->++++<]>--.++[----->+<]>.+++++.-.-.+[---->+<]>+++.++.+++[->+++<]>+.++.---------.+++++.++++++.+[--->+<]>+.[------>+<]>..-[->++++++<]>.[--->++<]>+.------------.++++++++.+++++.-[->+++++<]>-.-[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>+.[-->+++++++<]>.+++++.-.---[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>+++.--.[-->+++++<]>+++.-[->+++<]>-......-[->++++++<]>.---[->+++<]>-..............-[->++++++<]>.--[-->+++<]>.++++++++.[->++++<]>+.[----->++<]>++....[->++++++<]>-.-[++>-<]>---.[--->+<]>.++++++++.[->++++<]>+.[----->++<]>++....[->++++++<]>-.-[++>-<]>---.--[->++++<]>-.-.++[->++++<]>+.[----->++<]>++....[->++++++<]>-.-[++>-<]>---.[--->+<]>+.++++++.+[->++++<]>+.[----->++<]>++....[->++++++<]>-.-[++>-<]>---.++[++>---<]>+..............-[->++++++<]>.+++[->+++<]>.-[--->+<]>++.[---->+++<]>-......-[->++++++<]>.---[->+++<]>-..-[->++++++<]>.+++++++.-------.+++++++.---------.-[->++<]>-.>++++++++++.-[------->+<]>++.++++.------------.+++++++++++.
```

Made with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5418/brainf-golfer/5440#5440).
[TIO](https://tio.run/##pVNbCgIxDDxQaE4gvUjxQwVBBD8Ez1/zmLSpiogbFelsZpI0s8f74XI7P07X3olasai021f5Z/k1OdmRyWJgjircJomRIx@HDVXIvuRMhdilPEBDBWM6kXNHzFHZJNjTPK@kgE4ITpaNkSdquQ6U1zFi2FkP80iZwQlopBa2WNvNWkiIeE2E8uhE1eelx61gdlKFLKAzEtWCJbZ1OZu0lt2zL39rW3nvf2pJG3oqxahfrjZbUB@NhTLc@vP63nTj5cgOTA5PtgujwTPJ4bDsZzfrg96f)

### PostScript (New!)

```
(IO.puts "print(\\"main = putStr \\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"08á\\\\'←08á\\\\'←76á\\\\'←17á\\\\'←\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"o|\\\\\\"\\")") =
quit
```

(That's a lot of backslashes!)
[TIO](https://tio.run/#%23K8gvLilOLsosKNGtKACy///X8PTXKygtKVZQKijKzCvRiIlRyk3MzFOwVQCKBpcUKcSAgVIMClAysDi8EMRQf9Q2AZltboZgG5oj2Gja82vgxippKmkq2HIVlmYCXQMA)

### Elixir

```
IO.puts "print(\"main = putStr \\\"\\\\\\\"08á\\'←08á\\'←76á\\'←17á\\'←\\\\\\\"o|\\\"\")"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWEGpoCgzr0QjRik3MTNPwVYBKBhcUqQQExOjFAMBSgYWhxfGxKg/apuAYJmbwViG5jAWTH1@DVi3kqbS//8A)

### Python 3

```
print("main = putStr \"\\\"08á\'←08á\'←76á\'←17á\'←\\\"o|\"")
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQyk3MTNPwVahoLQkuKRIIUYpJiZGycDi8MIY9UdtE@AMczMow9AcygCpy6@JUVLS/P8fAA)

### Haskell

```
main = putStr "\"08á'←08á'←76á'←17á'←\"o|"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM0/BVqGgtCS4pEhBKUbJwOLwQvVHbRNgtLkZhDY0h9AxSvk1Sv//AwA)

### Haystack

```
"08á'←08á'←76á'←17á'←"o|
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y0isLC5JTM7@/1/JwOLwQvVHbRNgtLkZhDY0h9BK@TX//wMA)

### MY

```
08á'←08á'←76á'←17á'←
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y638/9/A4vBC9UdtE2C0uRmENjSH0P//AwA)

### MY output

```
PPCG
```

I’ll add some more later.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 -> Bash -> MySQL -> PHP

#### `int score = 4;`

---

```
print """echo "SELECT 'printf(\\"PPCG\\");';\""""
```

Even though this isn't code golf, the bytecount is 49.

---

Python outputs:

```
echo "SELECT 'printf(\"PPCG\");';"
```

Bash outputs:

```
SELECT 'printf("PPCG");';
```

MySQL outputs:

```
printf("PPCG");
```

PHP outputs:

```
PPCG
```

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

New to codegolf, just trying to make an entry. Not trying to win. Am I doing this right?

### Bash -> Batch - 23 bytes

```
printf "echo PPCG">.bat
```

This will output "echo PPCG" to a .bat which can be executed in windows.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  This answer looks perfectly valid, but I would recommend putting your score (2) in your title.  This question is a [tag:code-golf] question so there is no need to include your byte count unless you want to.

Comment: I think maybe wheat wizard forgot a "not" in there. This is _not_ code golf. Also, welcome 

Comment: @StewieGriffin "Code length of the first program will be the tie breaker." hmm...

Comment: I agree, but then the wizard's comment doesn't make sense: _This question is a code-golf question so there is no need to include your byte count_.