# Cycle my input please

Tags: code-golf, string

## Input

A string `s` of printable ASCII characters, newlines, and spaces (`0x20 ( )` to `0x7E (~)`), and a non-negative integer `n`.

## Challenge

To write a program that outputs either another program, or `s` depending on `n`. If `n = 1`, Then your code should output code which outputs `s`. If `n = 2`, Your code should output code which outputs code which outputs `s` and so on.

All outputted code should be in the same language as the language of the original submission.

## Test Cases

Format: `s, n -> output`
Assuming your submission is written in JavaScript:

```
No cycles, 0 -> No cycles
Hello, 1 -> console.log("Hello");
Cycle!, 3 -> console.log("console.log(\"console.log(\\\"Cycle!\\\")\")");
:), 3 -> console.log("console.log('console.log(`:)`)')");
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so aim for shortest code in bytes.

## Additional Rules

- I/O format is flexible
- Default rules and standard loopholes apply.
- The output of your submission must be valid.
- You can use any language, even if it was created after this challenge, as long as it wasn't created for the purpose of this challenge
- This isn't a polyglot challenge. A JavaScript submission shouldn't output Ruby code.
- Input is guaranteed to be valid as defined in the `Input` section

## Validation

Here's a quick tip to test your answers:
For `n=0`, `output=s`
For `n=1`, `eval(output)=s`
For `n=2`, `eval(eval(output))=s`
Where `n` and `s` are inputs

Comment: Are functions that output programs or functions allowed?

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107944/47066) [duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6544/47066)

Comment: @nwellnhof According to the default rules, yes.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Sorry, I mistyped, I meant the same language, not code

Comment: @Emigna, looks like a dupe to me.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
f=function(s,n)"if"(n,function()f(s,n-1),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jWCdPUykzTUkjTwcuppkGEtY11NQp1vyfpqGUkZqTk6@kY6ypAYZcQCEPiJCB5n8A)

Returns a zero-argument function that recursively calls `f` with `n` set to `n-1`. `n` successive function applications returns `s`.

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 3 bytes

```
ÀII
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3CDp@f//x6pOTn5CuH5RTkp/40B)

Takes string as input, prepends as many `I` as stated in the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 96 bytes

```
=Join("",If(B1,ArrayFormula("="&Rept("""",2^(Row(Offset(A1,0,0,B1))-1))),),A1,Rept("""",2^B1-1))
```

Inputs are in cells `A1` (`s`) and `B1` (`n`).

[image: Sample Results]

<sup>(Columns D, E, and F show the result if you copy the output from the column to its left and input it as a formula.)</sup>

---

The formula concatenates 3 pieces into a single string. The first piece is the most complicated.

```
If(B1,ArrayFormula("="&Rept("""",2^(Row(Offset(A1,0,0,B1))-1))),)
```

If `If` statement drops the prefix if `n=0` so you end up with `No cycles` instead of `="No cycles`. The `ArrayFormula` creates an array of equal signs followed by some number quotes. That number is `2^(x-1)` where `x` counts up from 1 to `n` thanks to the `Row(Offset(~))` combination.

The next piece (`A1`) adds in `s` and the final piece (`Rept("""",2^B1-1)`) adds in `2^n-1` quotes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
function($s,$n){while($n--)$s='echo'.var_export($s,1).';';return $s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcoxCsIwFADQPaf4w4ffQBuojrE4CR0Eu7kUitSEFEISklQF8eyRXkB88wsmlMMxmMAYauig6NXNefGuwlSj4@@nWayq0DUNx9SRmo0n8bjFSb2Cj3lrLRckSUaV1@gAk/wUydg2AXVFvbLWw0hXH@19JKqh5SBg6IfpdDnLX3H3b9xzWb4)

From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) about `var_export`:

> var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

This function calls `var_export` prepends `echo` and appends `;` `$n` times.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: 1) There´s no need for a space between `return` and `$s`. 2) recursive function, 67 bytes `function f($s,$n){return$n?f('echo'.var_export($s,1).';',$n-1):$s;}` 3) full program, 63 bytes: `for([,$s,$n]=$argv;$n--;)$s="echo".var_export($s,1).";";echo$s;` (run with `-r`)

Comment: I'd have to include `-r` in the byte count, don't I?

Comment: No, flags are free now; they count as a different language so, if you wanted to use that flag, this solution would be `PHP -r`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{'{Q«'x$^n~$^s~'»}'x$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wr068NBq9QqVuLw6lbjiOvVDu2uBvLza/2n5RQoaBjoK6n75CsmVyTmpxeqaOgoahkARj9ScnHwwzxjIcwZJKsK47/cuUkhMSlZQV4rJe793saaCrp2ChkqejoJKsaZCNRcn0GKV5PyUVAVbhTSYuDUXZ3EiVBzIhskrgRkxGppKeq5hjj4KIBfFqeShqq79DwA)

Function returning function code. Uses `Q« »` to quote unescaped ASCII strings.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

*Outputs a program that outputs a program that outp.... until `b=1`*

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>b?--b?`(f=${f})('${a}',${b})`:a:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclBCoQgFADQ/ZwiQvB/0KhmF1hX6VtZM0g/KtqIZ7cL1Nu@P110DPtvO/XK45SSM0DKomltp7XtenBGBBcRpAgUpRLBRuwbaqRMA68H@6nwPIODfGFPucq@iJ/nqV@nep0SMd0)

Comment: This does not match the test cases, the output for `f("hello", 2)` should be `console.log("console.log(\"hello\")")` or `console.log("console.log('hello')")`

Comment: Yes it is... it just outputs `console.log("hello")`

Comment: Does not work for `n=0`

Comment: Nevermind, it's just 1-indexed

Comment: Is the `b=0 -> ''` case required? If not I think you can save 5 bytes just by removing it. (Becomes even clearer if you use 0-indexing instead of 1-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
s#n|n<1=s|0<1="main=putStr"++show(s#(n-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1g5rybPxtC2uMYASCrlJmbm2RaUlgSXFClpaxdn5JdrFCtr5Okaamr@B8kp2CrkJhb4KmjEVCjo2ilAVPrkKagoKHkAzctXVFKu0FSINtDTM479DwA)

Comment: I think `...0<1=show$s#(n-1)` is enough, because we treat [values in Haskell as functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12945/34531).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 12+1 bytes, not competing

plain text is a valid PHP program, but, if `N` is not `0`, this fails for text containing `<?` with short tags enabled and for text containing `<?php`  or `<?=` in any case:

```php
<?=$argv[1];
```

call with `php -R '<code>' '<string>' <n>`;
call the output with `php -R '<code>'`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Ṿ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn2HFv7//7/4vxEA)

Comment: Explanation? How does this wor

Comment: @FireCubez It simply executes the value → string representation function `n` times.

Comment: And does executing the string representation of a value print the value?

Comment: @FireCubez The eval function (`V`) simply evaluates the code within a string. It doesn't implicitly print anything.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 55 bytes

```
c=lambda s,n:c("(lambda:"+repr(s)+")()",n-1)if n else s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), `-DA=asprintf(` `-lm` 136 bytes

```c
j,*c,*e;f(a,b){A&c,"%s",a);for(;b--;){e="";for(j=1;j++<pow(2,b);A&e,"\\%s",e));A&c,"puts(%s\"%s%s\");",e,c,e);}puts(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9LasMwEAbgtX0KIUiQlFET2U4KUb0wdNFVT5CNLKQ0Rn5gJbRgcvW6sqFgvJnRz8doGM21U811HCtgGpiRligo6VBsNeCNx6CotG1PZMm5pIPJMZ5zlQtZ7XZvXftNkjAgi60BfLlMI4ZOMcx3j7snG38JH02VymCgg8vnTDo8xltzR7W6NYQOcbRniJzglFJEjpCK0DIQx9BSeA01gUkECPqCPh91aXrUWuSd8l/Gn0nC2A/lArF9HM0LcJMfzmFvHFmCP4xzLYbDFP9VrFUsNVlrstR0relSs7VmIT7HX22duvqRvxe58l0frrdk5K7@Aw)