# Codegolf: Quine and Antiquine

Tags: code-golf, quine

This challenge is similar to [Can you Meta Quine?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5510/can-you-meta-quine)

A quine is a program that produces itself on STDOUT. This challenge is to produce a program A which when run produces a program B on STDOUT. Program B when run produces program A on STDOUT. Programs A and B must be written in (and run in) the same language. The linked question constrained A != B. That looked too easy. So for this question, we insist A and B are antiquines, using the following rules:

1. Programs A and B may not use any of the same characters, save for whitespace and statement separators, and punctuation characters.
2. Programs A and B must each contain at least one character that is neither whitespace nor a statement separator, nor a punctuation character.
3. For the purpose of rules 1 and 2, the term 'whitespace' excludes any symbol or sequence of symbols which itself is a statement, operator or symbol that is interpreted (as opposed to a separator). Therefore in the Whitespace language, there is no whitespace.
4. A statement separator is a syntactic element conventionally used within the language to separate statements. This would include the newline in python, or the semicolon in Java, perl or C.
5. A punctuation character is an ASCII character which is neither whitespace nor in the POSIX word character class (i.e. an underscore is not punctuation for this purpose) - i.e `ispunct()` would return true, and it's not `_`.
6. Program A when run must produce a program (Program B) on its STDOUT, which when run in turn produces Program A.
7. Programs A and B must be in the same programming language.
8. The programming language used must actually be a programming language. Unless you make a good case otherwise, I'll suggest it must be Turing complete.
9. At least one of A and B must execute at least one statement within the language.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins, the score being the length of program A in bytes (i.e. the length of program B is not relevant).

Comment: Can you please add "punctuation" to the list of exceptions in the first clause? It's impossible to solve this task in many languages (especially those that require you to you curly braces in the main function) otherwise.

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine) but probably sufficiently different.

Comment: @FUZxxl I've permitted punctuation marks but excluded underscores.

Comment: So just to make sure: Things like `'` and `"` are allowed to appear in both programs, correct?

Comment: @IngoBürk, yes, thinks like `'` and `"` can appear in both programs (per the exception at the end of rule 1). However there must be something that appears in each program that is NOT a punctuation mark, a whitespace character or a statement separator. IE you can't just produce a single quine made of punctuation marks, and say it is both A and B.

Comment: Can you use space/tab in python? It's part of the statement separator, just not always.

Comment: Your definition of whitespace is wrong. `print("Hello, World!")` is not the same as `pri nt("Hello, World!")`.

Comment: I guess Python is out. Can't imagine any of A or B not having a ```print``` command, causing both programs containing these 5 characters. (```sys.stdout.write``` contains ```r```, ```i``` and ```t``` as well.)

Comment: @isaacg you can use whitespace in any language (including Python), but there must also be non-whitespace characters.

Comment: @Doorknob thanks - I've clarified that.

Comment: For the purposes here, are `A` and `a` considered different "characters"?

Comment: It would be better if you provided a complete list of ASCII characters that match rule 5.

Comment: So, if `A` has 'class', `B` would have to use 'CLASS'?

Comment: @Ourous: If `A` has 'class', `B` would have to have something other than `class`; `CLASS` is but one option.

Comment: @aditsu: the POSIX word character class consists of the letters a-Z, A-Z, the numbers 0-9 and underscore (_).

Comment: @abligh that's not what I asked..

Comment: @aditsu I've made the rule rather simpler (similar to the definition of `ispunct()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## GolfScript, 13 bytes

```
1{\~\".~"}.~
```

The output is

```
-2{\~\".~"}.~
```

which generates the initial program.

The byte count include the trailing LF, since the output of the output will contain it.

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MXtcflwiLn4ifS5%2BICAgIyBQcm9ncmFtIEEKCm4gbiAgICAgICAgICAgICMgTmV3bGluZXMKCi0ye1x%2BXCIufiJ9Ln4gICMgUHJvZ3JhbSBC)

#### How it works

```
1       # Push 1.
{       # Start code block.
  \~\   # Apply logical NOT to the second topmost element of the stack.
  ".~"  # Push that string.
}       # End code block.
.~      # Duplicate the code block and execute the copy.
```

GolfScript prints the stack's contents upon termination.

Comment: Please read the problem statement again - `Programs A and B may not use any of the same characters, save for whitespace and statement separators, and punctuation characters.`

Comment: Everything but `1` and `2` is punctuation.

Comment: OK, the rules were changed since I last read them.

Comment: Yup, that works. I'd phrased the rules to prevent whitespace being used as statements, but forgot the same loophole would be present for punctuation. So loophole legally exploited.

Answer (score 14):

### Pascal (731 characters)

Program A:

```pascal
program s;{$h+}uses sysutils;const p='program s;{$h+}uses sysutils;const p=';a='a';aa=''';';aaa='a=''';aaaa='''';aaaaa='begin write(lowercase(p+aaaa+p+aa+aaa+a+aa+a+aaa+aaaa+aa+aa+a+a+aaa+aaa+aaaa+aa+a+a+a+aaa+aaaa+aaaa+aa+a+a+a+a+aaa+stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace(aaaaa,aaaa,aaaa+aaaa,[rfreplaceall]),''lower''+''c'',''tm''+''p'',[]),''up''+''c'',''lower''+''c'',[]),''tm''+''p'',''up''+''c'',[])+aa+aaaaa))end.';begin write(upcase(p+aaaa+p+aa+aaa+a+aa+a+aaa+aaaa+aa+aa+a+a+aaa+aaa+aaaa+aa+a+a+a+aaa+aaaa+aaaa+aa+a+a+a+a+aaa+stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace(aaaaa,aaaa,aaaa+aaaa,[rfreplaceall]),'lower'+'c','tm'+'p',[]),'up'+'c','lower'+'c',[]),'tm'+'p','up'+'c',[])+aa+aaaaa))end.
```

Outputs program B:

```pascal
PROGRAM S;{$H+}USES SYSUTILS;CONST P='PROGRAM S;{$H+}USES SYSUTILS;CONST P=';A='A';AA=''';';AAA='A=''';AAAA='''';AAAAA='BEGIN WRITE(UPCASE(P+AAAA+P+AA+AAA+A+AA+A+AAA+AAAA+AA+AA+A+A+AAA+AAA+AAAA+AA+A+A+A+AAA+AAAA+AAAA+AA+A+A+A+A+AAA+STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(AAAAA,AAAA,AAAA+AAAA,[RFREPLACEALL]),''LOWER''+''C'',''TM''+''P'',[]),''UP''+''C'',''LOWER''+''C'',[]),''TM''+''P'',''UP''+''C'',[])+AA+AAAAA))END.';BEGIN WRITE(LOWERCASE(P+AAAA+P+AA+AAA+A+AA+A+AAA+AAAA+AA+AA+A+A+AAA+AAA+AAAA+AA+A+A+A+AAA+AAAA+AAAA+AA+A+A+A+A+AAA+STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(STRINGREPLACE(AAAAA,AAAA,AAAA+AAAA,[RFREPLACEALL]),'LOWER'+'C','TM'+'P',[]),'UP'+'C','LOWER'+'C',[]),'TM'+'P','UP'+'C',[])+AA+AAAAA))END.
```

Outputs program A.

Comment: I am enjoying the (mis)use of case translation.

Answer (score 13):

## [ROT13](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROT13_encoder/decoder) (*not competing anymore after rule update*)

Not sure if this counts as a language, but I certainly didn't make it up for the challenge. Usually answers for certain utilities such as `sed` are accepted as well. However, it's a judgement call, so if it doesn't count I'll remove it (is there a meta discussion somewhere on what counts as a language? Edit: [There is now](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages))

```
A
```

Cycles between `A` and `N`:

```
~>> echo "A" | rot13
N
~>> echo "A" | rot13 | rot13
A
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work, as rot13 is simply taking input on `STDIN`, not executing a program. If you are arguing that it is a zero length program, that fails to satisfy rule 2. The program (with `sed`) is what's passed in `sed -e`. If this was acceptable, then `cat` would be a quine, and `tac` would be a quine and antiquine. However, nothing is producing the source to `cat`, `tac` or for that matter `rot13`.

Comment: @abligh If rot13 is the language used, why should I have to print the source code for rot13? Also, if I run Golfscript, Python or anything else, I will likely just pass the source code to it via stdin or file, so there isn't really any difference. In this case rot13 *is* the interpreter.

Comment: `rot13` as a programming language does not appear to satisfy any reasonable definition of 'programming language', and it's not interpreting anything. I will amend the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Fine with me. I'll leave this answer as not competing anymore and start a meta discussion. Nice challenge, by the way. Can't wait to see "real" solutions!